# Generate random string/characters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, random

I want a 5 character string composed of characters picked randomly from the set `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.

What's the best way to do this with JavaScript?

Comment: Warning: None of the answers have a `true-random` result! They are only `pseudo-random`. When using random strings for protection or security, don't use any of them!!! Try one of these api's: http://www.random.org/

Comment: Note [HTML5 webcrypto randomness API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RandomSource) provides real randomness.

Comment: If anyone is here looking to generate an id or unique identifier, let your DB do that job or use a UUID library instead.

Comment: [random string using javascript,Java, Python, Rust, bash](https://fe-tool.com/en-us/random-password)

Comment: Try npm library [random-ext](https://www.npmjs.com/package/random-ext)

Answer (score 3698, accepted):

I think this will work for you:

```js
function makeid(length) {
    let result = '';
    const characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    const charactersLength = characters.length;
    let counter = 0;
    while (counter < length) {
      result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
      counter += 1;
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(makeid(5));
```

Comment: @dan_waterworth It probably doesn't matter in almost *any* case: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater.html

Comment: it may look wrong, but `floor` is unneeded: for(var text=''; text.length < 5;) text += possible.charAt(Math.random() * possible.length)

Comment: @dan_waterworth, Actually, `+=` is often faster for some reason, even used inside loops - http://jsperf.com/join-vs-concatenation

Comment: @AlexReece That link doesn't say what you think it says. Doing "a"+"b" a million times is fine. Doing a += "b" a million times is not.

Comment: @JonathanPaulson *Show me the numbers*. See the previous comment with a jsperf link or http://jsperf.com/sad-tragedy-of-microoptimization or http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/05/09/string-performance-an-analysis/ etc. Also, this question involves only 5 concatenations.

Comment: Thanks! I used this but randomized the length. Instead of 5, I got another random number for length: Math.floor(Math.random() * maxLength)

Comment: @dan_waterworth - what you've said is true in other languages, not in javascript.

Comment: so i just crunched some numbers (ran it about ```10 million``` times) and with 5 characters you get about a ```0.05%``` duplication pretty consistently when you up the characters by even one that % drops to about ```0.0001%```. i plan on using this in my password salting and i will use a 10 character rand string and i think it will be perfect!

Comment: @codenamejames Please *do not* use this in your password salting. It is only pseudo-random not secure. Assuming you are using Node (I'm not even sure where to start if you're salting on the client side), use [`crypto`](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) instead.

Comment: @Hydrothermal what about [getRandomValues](http://caniuse.com/#feat=getrandomvalues)?

Comment: @JanusTroelsen `crypto.getRandomValues` will work; it does provide crypto-strong numbers, although it didn't exist at the time of my comment.

Comment: Is there any easy way to have those chars unique always?

Comment: @Hydrothermal the salt used on a password can usually be assumed to be public information, and doesn't need to be cryptographically secure.  It's there purely to reduce the risk of a pre-computed rainbow table existing.

Comment: What is this irrelevant discussion about performance? Who wants to generate a random string of a million characters? And if in 2017 we still have to peek under the hood when writing string concatenation, we haven't made any progress at all.

Comment: @HaiPhan lmao, too right. Didn't matter to me 8 years ago, damn sure doesn't now 

Comment: the v8 engine optimises the creation of strings based on older ones and so it isn't `O(n^2)`

Comment: I like this because it's really concise, easy to understand and doesn't use any libraries or advanced ecmascript features.

Comment: @dan_waterworth it only matters if you generate like 10 million character long strings lol

Comment: you can your pass : console.log("MZ-"+makeid(2)+"15");

Comment: Actually, in modern browsers string concatenation is 2-3 times faster than joining an array: https://jsben.ch/FCQ9w (which, I agree, would not matter in almost any case anyway). I modified the code snippet to use string concatenation.

Comment: I think @Mulan's answer below is better than this I think, which uses crypto lib `crypto.randomBytes(20).toString('hex');`

Answer (score 3178):

```js
//Can change 7 to 2 for longer results.
let r = (Math.random() + 1).toString(36).substring(7);
console.log("random", r);
```

Note: The above algorithm has the following weaknesses:

- It will generate anywhere between 0 and 6 characters due to the fact that trailing zeros get removed when stringifying floating points.
- It depends deeply on the algorithm used to stringify floating point numbers, which is horrifically complex. (See the paper ["How to Print Floating-Point Numbers Accurately"](https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/gcl-devel/2012-10/pdfkieTlklRzN.pdf).)
- `Math.random()` may produce predictable ("random-looking" but not really random) output depending on the implementation. The resulting string is not suitable when you need to guarantee uniqueness or unpredictability.
- Even if it produced 6 uniformly random, unpredictable characters, you can expect to see a duplicate after generating only about 50,000 strings, due to the [birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem). (sqrt(36^6) = 46656)

Comment: love it, but he needs [a-zA-Z]

Comment: `Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5)`, because `.substring(7)` causes it to be longer than 5 characters. Full points, still!

Comment: And an ActionScript 2 compatible version: `Math.round(Math.random()*Math.pow(36,5)).toString(36)`

Comment: @Scoop The `toString` method of a number type in javascript takes an optional parameter to convert the number into a given base. If you pass two, for example, you'll see your number represented in binary. Similar to hex (base 16), base 36 uses letters to represent digits beyond 9. By converting a random number to base 36, you'll wind up with a bunch of seemingly random letters and numbers.

Comment: Looks beautiful but in few cases this generates empty string! If random returns 0, 0.5, 0.25, 0.125... will result in empty or short string.

Comment: This produces a longer random number: 
(Math.PI * Math.max(0.01, Math.random())).toString(36).substr(2, 5);

Comment: @gertas This can be avoided by `(Math.random() + 1).toString(36).substring(7);`

Comment: To summarise, the ultimate script using @GeorgeReith and dragon's techniques is: (Math.random() +1).toString(36).substr(2, 5). It stops the string being empty and limits it to 5 chars.

Comment: @william44isme: If Math.random() returns 0.25, then the above will evaluate to `(1.25).toString(36).substr(2, 5)`, which will equal `9` - so it still won't work.  I did this: `function randomString() { var i = ''; while(i.length < 5) {i = Math.random().toString(36).slice(2);}; return i; }`, which gets me a string of at least 5

Comment: @AsfandYarQazi I'm not sure what the pattern is for producing such small strings so if anyone could explain that would be great. Although your solution (and adds some entropy in variation of token length) looks good and is what I am currently using.

Comment: "0" fix:  `('0000'+Math.random().toString(36).replace('.', '')).substr(-5);`

Comment: This solution only partly answers the question.  It will generate a random string of parts `[a-z0-9]`.  It will not include capital letters.  Still a very good trick nonetheless!

Comment: `(+new Date * Math.random()).toString(36).substring(0,5)`

Comment: I don't know if it's useless, but hacklikecrack is totally telling the truth. csharptest.net's algorithm generates far less duplicates. If you crank up the number of digits to 8, you'll find the duplicates drop to zero. thank you @hacklikecrack

Comment: Nice solution. However, I would rather use slice, so that the number of characters matches the given parameter. `Math.random().toString(36).slice(-5)`

Comment: @hacklikecrack, the duplicates occur because `substring(7)` takes the digits from the least significant part of the base-36 string. `toString(36)` appears to convert the random number to a 16 digit base-36 string, but the precision required for this would be 36^16 = 7.958e24 possible numbers, where the precision of Math.random() is only [4.5e15](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344447/math-random-question). Taking the digits from most significant end with `.slice(2,5)` solves this: [5 digit example](http://jsfiddle.net/dbbfmfdL/)

Comment: This might not work as expected in newer versions of Chrome (http://thenextweb.com/google/2015/12/17/google-chromes-javascript-engine-finally-returns-actual-random-numbers/#gref)

Comment: `length => (Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 2 + length) + '0'.repeat(length)).substring(0, length)`

Comment: All these comments make it pretty confusing as to what the actual best solution is here and whether the highly upvoted answer above is indeed the best direction, or one of the ones in the comments like this: `Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5)`  ?

Comment: I wrote this answer almost 9 years ago as a knee-jerk reaction to not show exactly the right answer (my mistake in intention) but to show only a potentially different way of thinking about the problem. At the time there was no answer similar to mine. Based on the comments above here, I think I accomplished my goal.

Comment: Not really helpful answer, yet too many up votes! it has too many issues.

Comment: If Math.random returns `0.5` then we get invalid result

Comment: Keep in mind that `String.prototype.substr()` is deprecated. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr

Answer (score 933):

[**Math.random** is bad for this kind of thing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14869745/633183)

**server side**

Use node [crypto](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) module -

```
var crypto = require("crypto");
var id = crypto.randomBytes(20).toString('hex');

// "bb5dc8842ca31d4603d6aa11448d1654"
```

The resulting string will be twice as long as the random bytes you generate; each byte encoded to hex is 2 characters. 20 bytes will be 40 characters of hex.

---

**client side**

Use the browser's crypto module, [crypto.getRandomValues](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/getRandomValues) -

> The `crypto.getRandomValues()` method lets you get cryptographically strong random values. The array given as the parameter is filled with random numbers (random in its cryptographic meaning).

```js
// dec2hex :: Integer -> String
// i.e. 0-255 -> '00'-'ff'
function dec2hex (dec) {
  return dec.toString(16).padStart(2, "0")
}

// generateId :: Integer -> String
function generateId (len) {
  var arr = new Uint8Array((len || 40) / 2)
  window.crypto.getRandomValues(arr)
  return Array.from(arr, dec2hex).join('')
}

console.log(generateId())
// "82defcf324571e70b0521d79cce2bf3fffccd69"

console.log(generateId(20))
// "c1a050a4cd1556948d41"
```

A step-by-step console example -

```
> var arr = new Uint8Array(4) # make array of 4 bytes (values 0-255)
> arr
Uint8Array(4) [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ]

> window.crypto
Crypto { subtle: SubtleCrypto }

> window.crypto.getRandomValues()
TypeError: Crypto.getRandomValues requires at least 1 argument, but only 0 were passed

> window.crypto.getRandomValues(arr)
Uint8Array(4) [ 235, 229, 94, 228 ]
```

For IE11 support you can use -

```
(window.crypto || window.msCrypto).getRandomValues(arr)
```

For browser coverage see https://caniuse.com/#feat=getrandomvalues

---

**client side (old browsers)**

If you must support old browsers, consider something like `uuid` -

```js
const uuid = require("uuid");
const id = uuid.v4();

// "110ec58a-a0f2-4ac4-8393-c866d813b8d1"
```

Comment: Note that for version 4 UUIDs, not all the characters are random. From Wikipedia: "Version 4 UUIDs have the form xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx where x is any hexadecimal digit and y is one of 8, 9, A, or B". (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29)

Comment: @wmassingham, I'm not sure I understand the purpose of your comment. Do you mean to imply something the concern of uniqueness due to some fixed characters in a v4 uuid ?

Comment: Exactly. While a UUID is fine for assigning an ID to a thing, using it as a string of random characters isn't a great idea for this (and probably other) reasons.

Comment: Safari 9.3 shows this error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '>'

Comment: @RonaldoBahia, Safari doesn't support arrow functions because it's a noob. Thanks for the notice.

Comment: crypto is the way to go if you are using Node.js. This deserves more upvotes.

Comment: No need for `.map()` in Option 3. `Array.from(arr, dec2hex).join('')` === `Array.from(arr).map(dec2hex).join('')`. Thanks for introducing me to these features :-)

Comment: should mention that synchronous version throws an Error unlike the async version which follows callback(err, data) convention.

Comment: You should mention in the answer that option 2 also needs node.js to work, it's not pure javascript.

Comment: @Esko node is used to create the front-end module but the result is pure javascript that runs directly in the browser. Packaging javascript using node is commonplace and there are countless utilities to help automate the task for you. However they are beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: For option 3, I would prefer something like this: `function generateId(len) {var arr = new Uint8Array(len);  window.crypto.getRandomValues(arr); return Array.from(arr, function(dec) { return Math.floor(dec / 16).toString(16); }).join('');}`

Comment: Also notice that IE 11 doesn't support `Array.from`, but it does support `window.crypto.getRandomValues`.

Comment: While being more cryptographically secure, this doesn't actually satisfy the requirements of the question because it only outputs 0-9 and a-f (Hexadecimal), and not 0-9, a-z, A-Z.

Comment: `('0' + dec.toString(16)).substr(-2)` now has a nicer form: `dec.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')`

Comment: What if I need a random string in the set `[a-zA-Z0-9]` of length N?

Comment: @jerrymouse write a program to do it? `Array.from(Array(N), _ => "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789".substr(Math.floor(Math.random() * 62), 1)).join("")`

Comment: @thank-you But as you suggested, I wanted to use cryptographic uniqueness.

Comment: I am using a node package, similar to your answer. `const cryptoRandomString = require('crypto-random-string');
cryptoRandomString({length: 100, type: 'base64'}).replace(/[/+=]/g,'').substr(-30);` I am generating a random base64 string of 100 characters. Then taking last 30 characters after removing unwanted characters (+,/,=).

Comment: **Beware, the `dec2hex()` function is wrong** (unless you actually want `15` to map to `f` instead of `0f`. To fix the function, the conditional must be updated to `dec < 16` from `dec < 10`. However, one could just go for more concise form already suggested by Amadan in a former comment: `dec.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')`

Comment: @AneesAhmed777 the `dec2hex` was provided an example encoder. It's up to you to represent the bytes however you choose. I updated the post with your suggestion.

Comment: @Mulan crypto is available to browsers as well. See [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=crypto)

Comment: @hitautodestruct thanks that was option 3 in the post. i reworded things to make it a little more clear that it was a browser module.

Answer (score 326):

### Short, easy and reliable

Returns exactly 5 random characters, as opposed to some of the top rated answers found here.

```
Math.random().toString(36).slice(2, 7);
```

Comment: What if `Math.random().toString(36)` returns a number with less than 5 characters?

Comment: SilverRingvee probably just copy-pasted [the comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349404/generate-random-string-characters-in-javascript#comment13539914_8084248) from @dragon in the second answer. Give credit when it's due.

Comment: Well, that's an interesting indictment from @Aperçu, I am not saying that I invented the solution but I've been using it in my projects for years now. And it has nothing to do with the comment you mentioned. And I am quite sure that in SO what matters is the most useful information in the right place and even if it already exists in some other place, too. Luckily, it seems like at least 51 guys have found this answer useful, you're welcome!

Comment: As @MichaelLitvin pointed out, this fails in certain instances.  Two examples are when `Math.random()` returns `0` or `1`.  In these cases, the result of the expression provided in this answer is simply `""`. :(

Comment: To avoid getting empty string in case of Math.random() returns 0 you can use `function getRandomString() {
    var result = '';
    while (!result) result = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2);
    return result;
};`

Comment: @rinogo Math.random() can return 0 but not 1 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Comment: Good to know, @mikep!  Still, that's at least one case (there may be more) in which this code is broken.  If nothing else, it needs a conditional about the "0 case" which makes this a little bit less "short and easy" :/

Comment: This method does seem to be limited to (a max) of 10 characters.... still cool though.

Comment: I ran this code 1,000,000,000 times and still didn't get an empty string: jsfiddle.net/mtp5730r I would say you're pretty safe from getting an empty string.

Comment: Is this OK? What if I want more than 5 characters (not what the question asks, but a reasonable use case for someone reading this question IMO)? How many characters can result from passing the result of `Math.random()` through `toString(36)`? I can probably find out, but I would imagine that the number of characters and the quality of randomness depend on the tricky details of how floating-point numbers work in Javascript. I wouldn't feel confident depending on this.

Comment: An event being statistically unlikely does not make it safe. If anyone is using this for any security related activity they are gambling on the improbability of `Math.random` not returning 0. Hope you never have to debug this event

Comment: This does not always return 5 characters. For example, `(0.5).toString(36).substr(2, 5)` yields `"i"`.

Comment: Note that `substr` is a 'legacy function' in Node.js, so I used `.slice(2, 5)`.

Comment: @Gooz I don't think the question mentioned Node.js anywhere.

Comment: @SilverRingvee Modern IDEs will mark `substr()` as deprecated in both Node and vanilla JS/TypeScript so @Gooz has a point.

Comment: @Purefan I'm sorry, but the entire industry of technological security is based on the premise that extremely unlikely=safe. With that argument, nothing is ever safe because they could just guess your privatekey/password/hash/etc. The only question is how unlikely is it, and is that unlikely enough for your application.

Comment: @SepehrNazari I dont see you disagreeing with my comment so I dont know if you expected a reply or not... I still hope that neither you nor OP dont have to debug that case

Comment: Like it. Put it in a loop with a "test+=", and was able to get a 20 digit random code. Might not be "secure", but as it's only to be used to create a fake offline ClickBank receipt number ...

Answer (score 191):

Here's an improvement on [doubletap's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8084248/1985033). The original has two drawbacks which are addressed here:

First, as others have mentioned, it has a small probability of producing short strings or even an empty string (if the random number is 0), which may break your application. Here is a solution:

```
(Math.random().toString(36)+'00000000000000000').slice(2, N+2)
```

Second, both the original and the solution above limit the string size N to 16 characters. The following will return a string of size N for any N (but note that using N > 16 will not increase the randomness or decrease the probability of collisions):

```
Array(N+1).join((Math.random().toString(36)+'00000000000000000').slice(2, 18)).slice(0, N)
```

Explanation:

1. Pick a random number in the range [0,1), i.e. between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive).
2. Convert the number to a base-36 string, i.e. using characters 0-9 and a-z.
3. Pad with zeros (solves the first issue).
4. Slice off the leading '0.' prefix and extra padding zeros.
5. Repeat the string enough times to have at least N characters in it (by Joining empty strings with the shorter random string used as the delimiter).
6. Slice exactly N characters from the string.

Further thoughts:

- This solution does not use uppercase letters, but in almost all cases (no pun intended) it does not matter.
- The maximum string length at N = 16 in the original answer is measured in Chrome. In Firefox it's N = 11. But as explained, the second solution is about supporting any requested string length, not about adding randomness, so it doesn't make much of a difference.
- All returned strings have an equal probability of being returned, at least as far as the results returned by Math.random() are evenly distributed (this is not cryptographic-strength randomness, in any case).
- Not all possible strings of size N may be returned. In the second solution this is obvious (since the smaller string is simply being duplicated), but also in the original answer this is true since in the conversion to base-36 the last few bits may not be part of the original random bits. Specifically, if you look at the result of Math.random().toString(36), you'll notice the last character is not evenly distributed. Again, in almost all cases it does not matter, but we slice the final string from the beginning rather than the end of the random string so that short strings (e.g. N=1) aren't affected.

**Update:**

Here are a couple other functional-style one-liners I came up with. They differ from the solution above in that:

- They use an explicit arbitrary alphabet (more generic, and suitable to the original question which asked for both uppercase and lowercase letters).
- All strings of length N have an equal probability of being returned (i.e. strings contain no repetitions).
- They are based on a map function, rather than the toString(36) trick, which makes them more straightforward and easy to understand.

So, say your alphabet of choice is

```
var s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
```

Then these two are equivalent to each other, so you can pick whichever is more intuitive to you:

```
Array(N).join().split(',').map(function() { return s.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * s.length)); }).join('');
```

and

```
Array.apply(null, Array(N)).map(function() { return s.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * s.length)); }).join('');
```

**Edit:**

I seems like [qubyte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18120932/1985033) and [Martijn de Milliano](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14944262/1985033) came up with solutions similar to the latter (kudos!), which I somehow missed. Since they don't look as short at a glance, I'll leave it here anyway in case someone really wants a one-liner :-)

Also, replaced 'new Array' with 'Array' in all solutions to shave off a few more bytes.

Comment: Why not just add 1? ```(Math.random()+1).toString(36).substring(7);```

Comment: Because adding 1 doesn't solve either of the two issues discussed here. For example, (1).toString(36).substring(7) produces an empty string.

Comment: Using `Math.random().toString(36).substring(2,7)` gives an expected result which is more like the `.substring(2, n+2)`

Comment: `Array.apply(null, {length: 5}).map(function() { return s.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * s.length)); }).join('')`

Comment: This is great, but when executed in Firefox with N=16, the last ~6 digits end up being zero... (But it does satisfy the OP's desire for 5 random chars though.)

Comment: @EdwardNewell That is a correct observation about Firefox and N > 11, although the solution and explanation are basically the same - specifically, using large N does not add any randomness, but does guarantee an exact string length, which the original solution lacked. I'll update the answer.

Comment: The updated part of this post is great, it passes the test described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349404/generate-random-string-characters-in-javascript#comment30312741_8084248 just fine and it is just as fast as the hacky approach.

Comment: this leads to substrings repetition

Answer (score 160):

The most compact solution, because [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) is shorter than [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring).  Subtracting from the end of the string allows to avoid floating point symbol generated by the [`random`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) function:

```
Math.random().toString(36).slice(-5);
```

or even

```
(+new Date).toString(36).slice(-5);
```

**Update:** Added one more approach using [`btoa`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa) method:

```
btoa(Math.random()).slice(0, 5);
btoa(+new Date).slice(-7, -2);
btoa(+new Date).substr(-7, 5);
```

```js
// Using Math.random and Base 36:
console.log(Math.random().toString(36).slice(-5));

// Using new Date and Base 36:
console.log((+new Date).toString(36).slice(-5));

// Using Math.random and Base 64 (btoa):
console.log(btoa(Math.random()).slice(0, 5));

// Using new Date and Base 64 (btoa):
console.log(btoa(+new Date).slice(-7, -2));
console.log(btoa(+new Date).substr(-7, 5));
```

Comment: `Math.random().toString(36).slice(-5);` - What if `Math.random()` returns `0.0`?

Comment: @x-ray, you will get `"0"` ;)

Comment: Exactly. ;) And if `Math.random()` returns `0.5` the result is `"0.i"`. Not sure if there are other edge cases. Just wanted to point out that this is not a correct answer to the question (5 characters from [a-zA-Z0-9]).

Comment: @x-ray, I'm not going to say that this is the right answer, I'm just saying that this is a compact version of the @doubletap answer above. I personally use `(+new Date + Math.random())` to prevent this case. Anyway, thanks for the note.

Comment: **I would not recommend using** `btoa` **especially not tie it to a date** for a variety of reasons. The mains ones are 1) It is reversible! Someone with that string could know when you generate it  2) It is predictable! With one string I could guess the next ones 3) Generating the string on the same second result the same token. 4) It doesn't use all chars since the date doesn't change that much.

Comment: Why not using `bota` at all? I commented on other answers but using this test case you can see you going to use only 14 chars out of 64 that base64 has to offer: `[...new Set([...Array(100000)].map(()=>btoa(Math.random()).substr(0, 5)).join(""))].sort()`

Comment: This gave me the same result in two different places after about 20 runs. Don't use.

Answer (score 136):

A newer version with **es6** [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

`[...Array(30)].map(() => Math.random().toString(36)[2]).join('')`

- The `30` is an arbitrary number, you can pick any token length you want
- The `36` is the maximum radix number you can pass to [numeric.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString), which means [all numbers and a-z lowercase letters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base36)
- The `2` is used to pick the 3rd index from the random string which looks like this: `"0.mfbiohx64i"`, we could take any index after `0.`

Comment: Could you explain? Especially why you pass 36 to toString() and why you choose the 3rd element?

Comment: nice, but this solution doesn't include [A-Z] characters as question requested, only [a-z0-9]

Comment: @NahuelGreco you can do  

[...Array(30)].map(() => Math.random().toString(36)[2]).join('').toUpperCase()

Comment: @tam.teixeira I think no, original question asked for mixed caps, each char must be chosen at random from the [a-zA-Z0-9] set. This answer doesn't satisfies that.

Comment: ```Array(30).fill().map(() => Math.random().toString(36).slice(2)).join('')```  to generate a huge random string

Comment: I would also add a `|| '0'` so that it falls back to `0` instead of `undefined` if `Math.random()` returns `0` (it never returns `1`)

Answer (score 119):

Something like this should work

```
function randomString(len, charSet) {
    charSet = charSet || 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    var randomString = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var randomPoz = Math.floor(Math.random() * charSet.length);
        randomString += charSet.substring(randomPoz,randomPoz+1);
    }
    return randomString;
}
```

Call with default charset [a-zA-Z0-9] or send in your own:

```
var randomValue = randomString(5);

var randomValue = randomString(5, 'PICKCHARSFROMTHISSET');
```

Comment: A variant of example here can be found here: http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/number/random.html

Comment: might as well just decrement `len` directly in a `while` loop

Comment: Thanks, I just posted below a coffeescript variation of this example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26682781/262379

Comment: If these are going to be used publically, then you should probably remove the vowels.  A little less entropy, but a lot safer as you can't generate any words that may offend people.  That is why I like this, since I can send in my own character string.  Good job.

Comment: note that on a Node server, it's this simple: `crypto.randomBytes(3).toString('hex')`  (3 bytes gives 6 chars, for example)

Answer (score 78):

```js
function randomstring(L) {
  var s = '';
  var randomchar = function() {
    var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 62);
    if (n < 10) return n; //1-10
    if (n < 36) return String.fromCharCode(n + 55); //A-Z
    return String.fromCharCode(n + 61); //a-z
  }
  while (s.length < L) s += randomchar();
  return s;
}
console.log(randomstring(5));
```

Comment: I like this the best. You could easily modify to accept extra parameters and return only nums, lowers, or caps. I don't think the ultra-compressed style is necessary `while(s.length< L) s+= randomchar();`

Comment: Also `while(L--)` will do it

Comment: Better to use the more robust `'A'.charCodeAt(0)` rather than the magic number `55` (and likewise for the `61`). Particularly since, on my platform anyway, the magic number that returns is `65`. That code will self-document better as well.

Comment: I created a minification optimized (46 bytes smaller) variant of your implementation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52412162

Answer (score 75):

## Random String Generator (Alpha-Numeric | Alpha | Numeric)

```js
/**
 * Pseudo-random string generator
 * http://stackoverflow.com/a/27872144/383904
 * Default: return a random alpha-numeric string
 * 
 * @param {Integer} len Desired length
 * @param {String} an Optional (alphanumeric), "a" (alpha), "n" (numeric)
 * @return {String}
 */
function randomString(len, an) {
  an = an && an.toLowerCase();
  var str = "",
    i = 0,
    min = an == "a" ? 10 : 0,
    max = an == "n" ? 10 : 62;
  for (; i++ < len;) {
    var r = Math.random() * (max - min) + min << 0;
    str += String.fromCharCode(r += r > 9 ? r < 36 ? 55 : 61 : 48);
  }
  return str;
}

console.log(randomString(10));      // i.e: "4Z8iNQag9v"
console.log(randomString(10, "a")); // i.e: "aUkZuHNcWw"
console.log(randomString(10, "n")); // i.e: "9055739230"
```

---

While the above uses additional checks for the desired *A/N, A, N* output,
let's break it down the to the essentials (Alpha-Numeric only) for a better understanding:

- Create a function that accepts an argument (desired length of the random String result)
- Create an empty string like `var str = "";` to concatenate random characters
- Inside a loop **create a `rand` index number** from **0 to 61** (0..9+A..Z+a..z = 62)
- Create a **conditional logic** to **Adjust/fix `rand`** (since it's 0..61) incrementing it by some number (see examples below) to get back the right `CharCode` number and the related Character.
- Inside the loop concatenate to `str` a `String.fromCharCode( incremented rand )`

Let's picture the **ASCII Character table** ranges:

```
_____0....9______A..........Z______a..........z___________  Character
     | 10 |      |    26    |      |    26    |             Tot = 62 characters
    48....57    65..........90    97..........122           CharCode ranges
```

`Math.floor( Math.random * 62 )` gives a range from `0..61` (what we need).
Let's fix the random to get the correct **charCode ranges**:

```
      |   rand   | charCode |  (0..61)rand += fix            = charCode ranges |
------+----------+----------+--------------------------------+-----------------+
0..9  |   0..9   |  48..57  |  rand += 48                    =     48..57      |
A..Z  |  10..35  |  65..90  |  rand += 55 /*  90-35 = 55 */  =     65..90      |
a..z  |  36..61  |  97..122 |  rand += 61 /* 122-61 = 61 */  =     97..122     |
```

**The [conditional operation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) logic** from the table above:

```
   rand += rand>9 ? ( rand<36 ? 55 : 61 ) : 48 ;
// rand +=  true  ? (  true   ? 55 else 61 ) else 48 ;
```

From the explanation above, here's the resulting **alpha-numeric snippet**:

```js
function randomString(len) {
  var str = "";                                // String result
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {              // Loop `len` times
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 62); // random: 0..61
    var charCode = rand += rand > 9 ? (rand < 36 ? 55 : 61) : 48; // Get correct charCode
    str += String.fromCharCode(charCode);      // add Character to str
  }
  return str; // After all loops are done, return the concatenated string
}

console.log(randomString(10)); // i.e: "7GL9F0ne6t"
```

Or if you will:

```js
const randomString = (n, r='') => {
  while (n--) r += String.fromCharCode((r=Math.random()*62|0, r+=r>9?(r<36?55:61):48));
  return r;
};

console.log(randomString(10))
```

Comment: For a reason I was not able to identify, `x.toString(36)` --- as is used in the above answers --- was not reliably generating the same characters when I compared the outputs of two apps that had different ES versions, and this function fixed this for me as it does not use `.toString()`!

Answer (score 73):

To meet requirement [a-zA-Z0-9] and length of 5 characters, use

For **Browser**:

```
btoa(Math.random().toString()).substring(10,15);
```

For **NodeJS**:

```
Buffer.from(Math.random().toString()).toString("base64").substring(10,15);
```

Lowercase letters, uppercase letters, and numbers will occur.

(it's typescript compatible)

Comment: I guess, Math.random() could lead to a base64-string with too few characters.

Comment: Adding on @Leif comment, this will only generate numbers between **1-5 and only 19 out of 52 letters**!(upper and lower case) To test just run it multiple time, `Set` it to see unique chars and then sort. one liner for that: `[...new Set([...Array(100000)].map(()=>btoa(Math.random()).substr(5, 5)).join(""))].sort()`

Comment: Why do we need `toString` in the browser example?

Comment: You're right. No need for `toString()`. But as I wanted to do something as "it's typescript compatible". So I left it that way.

Comment: `Math.random().toString()` will only use digits 0-9 which is anything but random.  You cant just base64 it and expect it to be random.  You need random seed data to create a random output.  Therefor this answer fails to answer the OPs question.

Comment: Phil, are you saying that the Math.random() function is not random? LOL numbers 0 to 9 have a smaller universe of variety, but they ARE random using Math.random()

Comment: can we use .substing(10,15) instead?

Answer (score 45):

The simplest way is:

```
(new Date%9e6).toString(36)
```

This generate random strings of 5 characters based on the current time. Example output is `4mtxj` or `4mv90` or `4mwp1`

The problem with this is that if you call it two times on the same second, it will generate the same string.

The safer way is:

```
(0|Math.random()*9e6).toString(36)
```

This will generate a random string of 4 or 5 characters, always diferent. Example output is like `30jzm` or `1r591` or `4su1a`

In both ways the first part generate a random number. The `.toString(36)` part cast the number to a base36 (alphadecimal) representation of it.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how this answers the question; This is a 7 year old question with many valid answers already.  If you choose to provide a new answer, you should really take extra care to make sure that your answer is well explained and documented.

Comment: If you use Date, why don't you just use it like: `(+new Date).toString(36)`

Comment: I like your random number solution but 9e6 gives only 9 millions possibilities over the 60.4 millions ones for 5 digits (36^5) so you could replace it with `(0|Math.random()*6.04e7).toString(36)` to cover it.

Comment: I wanted a longish random string with a short-as-possible routine (for a code demo) that doesn't need to be cryptographically amazing, just produce some nice random visual "fluff". I like this answer the best (your 2nd one), so thank you. My two cents: I can beat it for shortness with one less keystroke, and it will typically produce 13 random characters (without a period): `(Math.random()*1e20).toString(36)`.

Comment: one qualm I have with this answer is that it will not use [A-Z] which happens to be in the original question.

Comment: The "simplest way" doesn't create random strings at all; it creates highly predictable strings with the superficial appearance of being random.

Comment: This should not be used if you need more than one string at a time. Date only has millisecond precision, so you can easily generate thousands of identical strings before the next millisecond ticks over.

Answer (score 37):

Here are some easy one liners. Change `new Array(5)` to set the length.

#### Including `0-9a-z`

```
new Array(5).join().replace(/(.|$)/g, function(){return ((Math.random()*36)|0).toString(36);})
```

#### Including `0-9a-zA-Z`

```
new Array(5).join().replace(/(.|$)/g, function(){return ((Math.random()*36)|0).toString(36)[Math.random()<.5?"toString":"toUpperCase"]();});
```

#### Codegolfed for ES6 (`0-9a-z`)

```
Array(5).fill().map(n=>(Math.random()*36|0).toString(36)).join('')
```

Answer (score 28):

There is *no best way* to do this. You can do it any way you prefer, as long as the result suits your requirements. To illustrate, I've created many different examples, all which should provide the same end-result

Most other answers on this page ignore the upper-case character requirement.

Here is my **fastest solution** and **most readable**. It basically does the same as the accepted solution, except it is a bit faster.

```
function readableRandomStringMaker(length) {
  for (var s=''; s.length < length; s += 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'.charAt(Math.random()*62|0));
  return s;
}
console.log(readableRandomStringMaker(length));
// e3cbN
```

Here is a **compact, recursive** version which is much less readable:

```
const compactRandomStringMaker = (length) => length-- && "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789".charAt(Math.random()*62|0) + (compactRandomStringMaker(length)||"");
console.log(compactRandomStringMaker(5));
// DVudj
```

A **more compact one-liner**:

```
Array(5).fill().map(()=>"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789".charAt(Math.random()*62)).join("")
// 12oEZ
```

A variation of the above:

```
"     ".replaceAll(" ",()=>"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789".charAt(Math.random()*62))
```

The **most compact** one-liner, but inefficient and unreadable - it adds random characters and removes illegal characters until length is *l*:

```
((l,f=(p='')=>p.length<l?f(p+String.fromCharCode(Math.random()*123).replace(/[^a-z0-9]/i,'')):p)=>f())(5)
```

A *cryptographically secure* version, which is wasting entropy for compactness, and is a waste regardless because the generated string is so short:

```
[...crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(999))].map((c)=>String.fromCharCode(c).replace(/[^a-z0-9]/i,'')).join("").substr(0,5)
// 8fzPq
```

Or, without the length-argument it is even shorter:

```
((f=(p='')=>p.length<5?f(p+String.fromCharCode(Math.random()*123).replace(/[^a-z0-9]/i,'')):p)=>f())()
// EV6c9
```

Then a bit more challenging - using a **nameless recursive arrow function**:

```
((l,s=((l)=>l--&&"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789".charAt(Math.random()*62|0)+(s(l)||""))) => s(l))(5);
// qzal4
```

This is a **"magic" variable** which provides a random character every time you access it:

```
const c = new class { [Symbol.toPrimitive]() { return "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789".charAt(Math.random()*62|0) } };
console.log(c+c+c+c+c);
// AgMnz
```

A simpler variant of the above:

```
const c=()=>"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789".charAt(Math.random()*62|0);
c()+c()+c()+c()+c();
// 6Qadw
```

Answer (score 26):

I know everyone has got it right already, but i felt like having a go at this one in the most lightweight way possible(light on code, not CPU):

```js
function rand(length, current) {
  current = current ? current : '';
  return length ? rand(--length, "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz".charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * 60)) + current) : current;
}

console.log(rand(5));
```

It takes a bit of time to wrap your head around, but I think it really shows how awesome javascript's syntax is.

Comment: If you're trying to keep the code short, why write `current = current ? current : '';` when you can write `current = current || ''`;

Comment: since we're talking micro optimization here i would actually suggest to skip the variable assignment entirely if not necessary: `current || (current = '');`

Comment: Attempting micro optimization while using a "nice" but resource wasting recursive algorithm makes no sense :-) A for loop still is best in Javascript and beats recursion big time, until really big advances in the optimizing code of the runtimes are made.

Answer (score 25):

Generate a secure random alphanumeric `Base-62` string:

```js
function generateUID(length)
{
    return window.btoa(String.fromCharCode(...window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(length * 2)))).replace(/[+/]/g, "").substring(0, length);
}

console.log(generateUID(22)); // "yFg3Upv2cE9cKOXd7hHwWp"
console.log(generateUID(5)); // "YQGzP"
```

Answer (score 19):

In case anyone is interested in a one-liner (although not formatted as such for your convenience) that allocates the memory at once (but note that for small strings it really does not matter) here is how to do it:

```
Array.apply(0, Array(5)).map(function() {
    return (function(charset){
        return charset.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charset.length))
    }('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'));
}).join('')
```

You can replace `5` by the length of the string you want. Thanks to @AriyaHidayat in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751520/how-to-generate-sequence-of-numbers-chars-in-javascript) for the solution to the `map` function not working on the sparse array created by `Array(5)`.

Comment: Every javascript program is a 'one-liner' if you format it as such

Answer (score 19):

If you're using [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) or [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/):

```
var randomVal = _.sample('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789', 5).join('');
```

Comment: Lodash uses `_.sampleSize('asdfgh',5).join('')`

Comment: This actually is not a good solution, because _per docs_ each character is from a unique index.  That means it's not truly random, since no character can / will ever repeat.

Answer (score 17):

```js
const c = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'
const s = [...Array(5)].map(_ => c[~~(Math.random()*c.length)]).join('')
```

Answer (score 15):

Here's the method I created.
It will create a string containing both uppercase and lowercase characters.
In addition I've included the function that will created an alphanumeric string too.

**Working examples:**
http://jsfiddle.net/greatbigmassive/vhsxs/  (alpha only)
http://jsfiddle.net/greatbigmassive/PJwg8/ (alphanumeric)

```
function randString(x){
    var s = "";
    while(s.length<x&&x>0){
        var r = Math.random();
        s+= String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(r*26) + (r>0.5?97:65));
    }
    return s;
}
```

**Upgrade July 2015**
This does the same thing but makes more sense and includes all letters.

```
var s = "";
while(s.length<x&&x>0){
    v = Math.random()<0.5?32:0;
    s += String.fromCharCode(Math.round(Math.random()*((122-v)-(97-v))+(97-v)));
}
```

Comment: With this function, you can never get an uppercase letter greater than 'M' or a lowercase letter lesser than 'n'.

Comment: Really? ooh! will probably test it more then. Hmm, however, given it's a random string and we don't really care what letters are in it (as long as they are random) then it still does what we want it to do which is all that matters but yes, will provide an upgrade, thanks.

Answer (score 15):

One liner:

```
Array(15).fill(null).map(() => Math.random().toString(36).substr(2)).join('')
// Outputs: 0h61cbpw96y83qtnunwme5lxk1i70a6o5r5lckfcyh1dl9fffydcfxddd69ada9tu9jvqdx864xj1ul3wtfztmh2oz2vs3mv6ej0fe58ho1cftkjcuyl2lfkmxlwua83ibotxqc4guyuvrvtf60naob26t6swzpil
```

Comment: To make it shorter change argument in `Array(15)` to a smaller value. E.g.: `Array(4)`.

Comment: I really love this solution, simple and clear. It is generating 15 random numbers between 0 and 1, generate the hexadecimal, and then remove the first two chars. Finally it is merging all of them together.

Comment: erroneous solution, uppercase characters aren't generated.

Answer (score 15):

Improved @Andrew's answer above :

```
Array.from({ length : 1 }, () => Math.random().toString(36)[2]).join('');
```

Base 36 conversion of the random number is inconsistent, so selecting a single indice fixes that. You can change the length for a string with the exact length desired.

Answer (score 14):

Assuming you use [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/) it's possible to elegantly generate random string in just two lines:

```
var possible = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
var random = _.sample(possible, 5).join('');
```

Comment: This will make the returned value have all unique chars. Also, the length of the string is limited up to the the length of var possible.

Answer (score 14):

Whilst this answer is almost similar to others, it differs in that it uses:

- `repeat` to create 5 characters (can be generalized to `n`)
- `replace` with regex `/./g` to replace those 5 characters
- the formula is random pick a character from a 62 character A-Za-z0-9 string

```js
let ans = "x".repeat(5)
             .replace(/./g, c => "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"[Math.floor(Math.random() * 62) ] );
console.log(ans);
```

Answer (score 13):

```
function randomString (strLength, charSet) {
    var result = [];
    
    strLength = strLength || 5;
    charSet = charSet || 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    
    while (strLength--) { // (note, fixed typo)
        result.push(charSet.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charSet.length)));
    }
    
    return result.join('');
}
```

This is as clean as it will get. It is fast too, http://jsperf.com/ay-random-string.

Comment: For me this always generates random strings with `strLength - 1` :-/

Comment: Switching from `--strLength` to `strLength--`fixes it for me.

Comment: @Gajus I took the liberty of fixing the obvious typo.  it is `strLength--` postfix, not prefix.

Comment: thank you sir. Wrapping it in a func make it easy to copy/paste ❤️

Answer (score 11):

Fast and improved algorithm. Does not guarantee uniform (see comments).

```
function getRandomId(length) {
    if (!length) {
        return '';
    }

    const possible =
        'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    let array;

    if ('Uint8Array' in self && 'crypto' in self && length <= 65536) {
        array = new Uint8Array(length);
        self.crypto.getRandomValues(array);
    } else {
        array = new Array(length);

        for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            array[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 62);
        }
    }

    let result = '';

    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        result += possible.charAt(array[i] % 62);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Great answer, but probability is not uniform. There are 62 possible characters and `crypto.getRandomValues` returns one of 256 unique values. Because 256 is not divided by 62, you end up having slightly higher probability of getting characters A-H. I think the best solution is to do what YouTube did, and just add 2 additional characters (possibly `-` and `_`) to the charset. Anyway, great work - this answer needs so much more love :)

Comment: adding - and _ is a great idea since it will get you the complete url-safe base64 set

Answer (score 10):

You can loop through an array of items and recursively add them to a string variable, for instance if you wanted a random DNA sequence:

```js
function randomDNA(len) {
  len = len || 100
  var nuc = new Array("A", "T", "C", "G")
  var i = 0
  var n = 0
  s = ''
  while (i <= len - 1) {
    n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)
    s += nuc[n]
    i++
  }
  return s
}

console.log(randomDNA(5));
```

Answer (score 10):

How about this compact little trick?

```
var possible = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
var stringLength = 5;

function pickRandom() {
    return possible[Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length)];
}

var randomString = Array.apply(null, Array(stringLength)).map(pickRandom).join('');
```

You need the `Array.apply` there to trick the empty array into being an array of undefineds.

If you're coding for ES2015, then building the array is a little simpler:

```
var randomString = Array.from({ length: stringLength }, pickRandom).join('');
```

Answer (score 10):

### Case Insensitive Alphanumeric Chars:

```js
function randStr(len) {
  let s = '';
  while (s.length < len) s += Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, len - s.length);
  return s;
}

// usage
console.log(randStr(50));
```

The benefit of this function is that you can get different length random string and it ensures the length of the string.

### Case Sensitive All Chars:

```js
function randStr(len) {
  let s = '';
  while (len--) s += String.fromCodePoint(Math.floor(Math.random() * (126 - 33) + 33));
  return s;
}

// usage
console.log(randStr(50));
```

### Custom Chars

```js
function randStr(len, chars='abc123') {
  let s = '';
  while (len--) s += chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];
  return s;
}

// usage
console.log(randStr(50));
console.log(randStr(50, 'abc'));
console.log(randStr(50, 'aab')); // more a than b
```

Comment: This answer has fit more for my use case.

It would be cool if you could add a `var possible` like in the accepted answer, so the outcome of the function is more configurable.

Answer (score 9):

The problem with responses to *"I need random strings"* questions (in whatever language) is practically every solution uses a flawed primary specification of *string length*. The questions themselves rarely reveal why the random strings are needed, but I would challenge you rarely need random strings of length, say 8. What you invariably need is some number of *unique strings*, for example, to use as identifiers for some purpose.

There are two leading ways to get *strictly unique* strings: deterministically (which is not random) and store/compare (which is onerous). What do we do? We give up the ghost. We go with *probabilistic uniqueness* instead. That is, we accept that there is some (however small) risk that our strings won't be unique. This is where understanding [*collision probability*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Cast_as_a_collision_problem) and [*entropy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) are helpful.

So I'll rephrase the invariable need as needing some number of strings with a small risk of repeat. As a concrete example, let's say you want to generate a potential of 5 million IDs. You don't want to store and compare each new string, and you want them to be random, so you accept some risk of repeat. As example, let's say a risk of less than 1 in a trillion chance of repeat. So what length of string do you need?  Well, that question is underspecified as it depends on the characters used. But more importantly, it's misguided. What you need is a specification of the entropy of the strings, not their length. Entropy can be directly related to the probability of a repeat in some number of strings. String length can't.

And this is where a library like [EntropyString](https://github.com/EntropyString/JavaScript) can help. To generate random IDs that have less than 1 in a trillion chance of repeat in 5 million strings using `entropy-string`:

```
import {Random, Entropy} from 'entropy-string'

const random = new Random()
const bits = Entropy.bits(5e6, 1e12)

const string = random.string(bits)
```

> "44hTNghjNHGGRHqH9"

`entropy-string` uses a character set with 32 characters by default. There are other predefined characters sets, and you can specify your own characters as well. For example, generating IDs with the same entropy as above but using hex characters:

```
import {Random, Entropy, charSet16} from './entropy-string'

const random = new Random(charSet16)
const bits = Entropy.bits(5e6, 1e12)

const string = random.string(bits)
```

> "27b33372ade513715481f"

Note the difference in string length due to the difference in total number of characters in the character set used. The risk of repeat in the specified number of potential strings is the same. The string lengths are not. And best of all, the risk of repeat and the potential number of strings is explicit. No more guessing with string length.

Comment: Thanks! Your comment made me realize I shouldn't be generating IDs randomly. It looks like `nanoid` is much more popular than `entropy-string` and seems just as good for my purposes.

Answer (score 9):

## Crypto-Strong

If you want to get [crypto-strong](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/getRandomValues) string which meets your requirements (I see answer which use this but gives non valid answers) use

```
let pass = n=> [...crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(n))]
   .map((x,i)=>(i=x/255*61|0,String.fromCharCode(i+(i>9?i>35?61:55:48)))).join``
```

```js
let pass = n=> [...crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(n))]
   .map((x,i)=>(i=x/255*61|0,String.fromCharCode(i+(i>9?i>35?61:55:48)))).join``

console.log(pass(5));
```

Update: thanks to [Zibri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/236062/zibri) comment I update code to get arbitrary-long password

Answer (score 7):

Here's a **functional style** approach. The performance is sub-optimal but it was fun to write -

```js
const char = a =>
  String .fromCharCode (a)

const irand = x =>
  Math .floor (Math .random () * x)

const sample = xs =>
  xs .at (irand (xs.length))

const range = x => y =>
  x > y
    ? []
    : [ x, ...range (x + 1) (y) ]

const srand = rs => n =>
  n <= 0
    ? ""
    : char (sample (rs)) + srand (rs) (n - 1)

const identifier = srand ([
  ...range (48) (57),   // include 0-9
  ...range (65) (90),   // include A-Z
  ...range (97) (122),  // include a-z
])

console .log (identifier (6))  //=> xUCXPI
console .log (identifier (10)) //=> JQvct8XeGt
console .log (identifier (20)) //=> ZVDwQSdRQLJEF5Wqjs17
```

It's hard to beat the clarity of `identifier`. Maybe a slight improvement could be -

```
const ord = x =>
  x .charCodeAt (0)

const idGenerator = srand ([
  ...range (ord('0')) (ord('9')),
  ...range (ord('A')) (ord('Z')),
  ...range (ord('a')) (ord('z')),
])
```

Have fun with it. Let me know what you like/learn ^_^

Comment: Great solution and I like that you derive `fold` from `foldk` :D

Comment: What are `U`, `Y` and `foldk`? I'm trying to understand this but I'm not that familiar with functional programming and, in all honesty, have no idea what to look up. Also, I did a benchmark using Deno to compare this method with the equivalent imperative one and, as suspected, it is 4x slower 

Comment: @TeodorMaxim to understand `U` and `Y` you will have to look into [combinatory logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic). `foldk` is a variant of `fold` (or `reduce`) which uses [continuation-passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style). I re-worked the answer to be more practical and less concerned with functional primitives. You will find the performance to be greatly improved in this revision. Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: I used `const irand = x => {
            let value: number | undefined
            const arr = new Uint8Array(1)
            while (value === undefined || value >= x) {
                self.crypto.getRandomValues(arr)
                value = arr.at(0)
            }
            return value
        }` to avoid Math.random. But blocks of code does not whow well in comments...

Answer (score 7):

I did not find a clean solution for supporting both lowercase and uppercase characters.

Lowercase only support:

`Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5)`

Building on that solution to support lowercase and uppercase:

`Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5).split('').map(c => Math.random() < 0.5 ? c.toUpperCase() : c).join('');`

Change the `5` in `substr(2, 5)` to adjust to the length you need.

Answer (score 7):

One-liner using *map* that gives you full control on the length and characters.

```
const rnd = (len, chars='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789') => [...Array(len)].map(() => chars.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length))).join('')

console.log(rnd(12))
```

Answer (score 7):

Just a simple `map` or `reduce` implementation should suffice:

```js
const charset: string =
  "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

const random1: string = [...Array(5)]
  .map((_) => charset[Math.floor(Math.random() * charset.length)])
  .join("");

const random2: string = [...Array(5)]
  .reduce<string>(
    (acc) => acc += charset[Math.floor(Math.random() * charset.length)],
    "",
  );
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is my approach (with TypeScript).

I've decided to write yet another response because I didn't see any simple solution using modern js and clean code.

```
const DEFAULT_ALPHABET = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';

function getRandomCharFromAlphabet(alphabet: string): string {
  return alphabet.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length));
}

function generateId(idDesiredLength: number, alphabet = DEFAULT_ALPHABET): string {
  /**
   * Create n-long array and map it to random chars from given alphabet.
   * Then join individual chars as string
   */
  return Array.from({length: idDesiredLength}).map(() => {
    return getRandomCharFromAlphabet(alphabet);
  }).join('');
}

generateId(5); // jNVv7
```

Answer (score 5):

This works for sure

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function randomString() {
 var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
 var string_length = 8;
 var randomstring = '';
 for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
  var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
  randomstring += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
 }
 document.randform.randomfield.value = randomstring;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

Generate 10 characters long string. Length is set by parameter (default 10).

```
function random_string_generator(len) {
var len = len || 10;
var str = '';
var i = 0;

for(i=0; i<len; i++) {
    switch(Math.floor(Math.random()*3+1)) {
        case 1: // digit
            str += (Math.floor(Math.random()*9)).toString();
        break;

        case 2: // small letter
            str += String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random()*26) + 97); //'a'.charCodeAt(0));
        break;

        case 3: // big letter
            str += String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random()*26) + 65); //'A'.charCodeAt(0));
        break;

        default:
        break;
    }
}
return str;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what I used. A combination of a couple here. I use it in a loop, and each ID it produces is unique. It might not be 5 characters, but it's guaranteed unique.

```
var newId =
    "randomid_" +
    (Math.random() / +new Date()).toString(36).replace(/[^a-z]+/g, '');
```

Comment: For what it's worth, this is not *guaranteed* unique, it is just very likely to be unique. Consider that Math.random() might return zero twice. Moreover, if two different base-36 numbers being fed into .replace(/[^a-z]+/g, ''); have the same sequence of non-numeric characters (e.g. abc1 and abc2), they will return the same ID.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a test script for the #1 answer (thank you @csharptest.net)

The script runs `makeid()` `1 million` times and as you can see 5 isn't a very unique. running it with a char length of 10 is quite reliable. I've ran it about 50 times and haven't seen a duplicate yet `:-)`

Note: node stack size limit exceeds around 4 million so you cant run this 5 million times it won't ever finish.

```
function makeid()
{
    var text = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for( var i=0; i < 5; i++ )
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

    return text;
}

ids ={}
count = 0
for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    tempId = makeid();
    if (typeof ids[tempId] !== 'undefined') {
        ids[tempId]++;
        if (ids[tempId] === 2) {
            count ++;
        }
        count++;
    }else{
        ids[tempId] = 1;
    }
}
console.log("there are "+count+ ' duplicate ids');
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [coderain](https://github.com/toolity/coderain). It's a library to generate random codes according to given pattern. Use `#` as a placeholder for upper and lowercase characters as well as digits:

```
var cr = new CodeRain("#####");
console.log(cr.next());
```

There are other placeholders like `A` for uppercase letters or `9` for digits.

What may be useful is that calling `.next()` will always give you a unique result so you don't have to worry about duplicates.

Here is a demo application that [generates a list of unique random codes](https://toolity.org/random-codes/).

*Full disclosure: I'm the author of coderain.*

Comment: NO NO NO - use native methods.

Answer (score 4):

This one combines many of the answers give.

```js
var randNo = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 2 + "" + new Date().getTime() +  Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 2 + (Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^a-zA-Z]+/g, '').substr(0, 5));

console.log(randNo);
```

I have been using it for 1 month with great results.

Answer (score 4):

How about something like this: `Date.now().toString(36)`
Not very random, but short and quite unique every time you call it.

Comment: Unfortunately this won’t be unique, as `Date.now()` only has millisecond resolution. When run in a simple loop, for example, you’ll get lots of duplicates. `for (let i = 0; i < 10; ++i) { console.log(Date.now().toString(36)); }`.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want uppercase letters (A-Z):

```js
randomAZ(n: number): string {
      return Array(n)
        .fill(null)
        .map(() => Math.random()*100%25 + 'A'.charCodeAt(0))
        .map(a => String.fromCharCode(a))
        .join('')
 }
```

If you just want the first letter to be uppercase (A-Z), and the rest to be lower case (a-z):

```js
function RandomWord(n: number): string {
    return Array(n)
      .fill(null)
      .map(() => Math.random()*100%25 + 'A'.charCodeAt(0))
      .map((a, i) => i === 0? String.fromCharCode(a) : String.fromCharCode(a+32))
      .join('')
}
```

Comment: The set should be `[a-zA-Z0-9]`

Answer (score 4):

One liner [a-z]:

```js
String.fromCharCode(97 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 26))
```

Comment: You still need to compose the string to the length it was asked. And this only generates random characters from [a-b] lowercase. What about uppercase and numbers as it was asked as well on the question?

Answer (score 4):

If you are developing on node js, it is better to use crypto. Here is an example of implementing the `randomStr()` function

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const charset = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
const randomStr = (length = 5) => new Array(length)
    .fill(null)
    .map(() => charset.charAt(crypto.randomInt(charset.length)))
    .join('');
```

If you are not working in a server environment, just replace the random number generator:

```
const charset = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
const randomStr = (length = 5) => new Array(length)
    .fill(null)
    .map(() => charset.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charset.length)))
    .join('');
```

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on Doubletap's elegant example by answering the issues Gertas and Dragon brought up. Simply add in a while loop to test for those rare null circumstances, and limit the characters to five.

```
function rndStr() {
    x=Math.random().toString(36).substring(7).substr(0,5);
    while (x.length!=5){
        x=Math.random().toString(36).substring(7).substr(0,5);
    }
    return x;
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle alerting you with a result: 
http://jsfiddle.net/pLJJ7/

Answer (score 2):

This will generate a random alpha-numeric string with the length of the first/calling string:

```
"12345".split('').map(function(){return 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'.charAt(Math.floor(62*Math.random()));}).join('');

//or

String.prototype.rand = function() {return this.split('').map(function(){return 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'.charAt(Math.floor(62*Math.random()));}).join('');};
```

Answer (score 2):

Also based upon doubletap's answer, this one handles any length of random required characters (lower only), and keeps generating random numbers until enough characters have been collected.

```
function randomChars(len) {
    var chars = '';

    while (chars.length < len) {
        chars += Math.random().toString(36).substring(2);
    }

    // Remove unnecessary additional characters.
    return chars.substring(0, len);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If a library is a possibility, Chance.js might be of help: http://chancejs.com/#string

Answer (score 2):

#### Random unicode string

This method will return a random string with any of the supported unicode characters, which is not 100% what OP asks for, but what I was looking for:

```
function randomUnicodeString(length){
    return Array.from({length: length}, ()=>{
        return String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * (65536)))
    }).join('')
}
```

#### Rationale

This is the top result of google when searching for "random string javascript", but OP asks for a-zA-Z0-9 only.

Answer (score 2):

For a string with upper- and lowercase letters and digits (0-9a-zA-Z), this may be the version that minifies best:

```
function makeId(length) {
  var id = '';
  var rdm62;
  while (length--) {
   // Generate random integer between 0 and 61, 0|x works for Math.floor(x) in this case 
   rdm62 = 0 | Math.random() * 62; 
   // Map to ascii codes: 0-9 to 48-57 (0-9), 10-35 to 65-90 (A-Z), 36-61 to 97-122 (a-z)
   id += String.fromCharCode(rdm62 + (rdm62 < 10 ? 48 : rdm62 < 36 ? 55 : 61)) 
  }
  return id;
}
```

The content of this function minifies to 97 bytes, while the top answer needs 149 bytes (because of the characters list).

Answer (score 2):

This is a slightly improved version of [doubletap](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1040319/doubletap)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8084248/402322). It considers [gertas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/446210/gertas)'s comment about the case, when `Math.random()` returns 0, 0.5, 0.25, 0.125, etc.

```
((Math.random()+3*Number.MIN_VALUE)/Math.PI).toString(36).slice(-5)
```

1. It prevents that zero gets passed to `toString` my adding the smallest float to `Math.random()`.
2. It ensures that the number passed to `toString` has enough digits by dividing through an almost irrational number.

Answer (score 2):

How about this below... this will produce the really random values:

```
function getRandomStrings(length) {
  const value = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
  const randoms = [];
  for(let i=0; i < length; i++) {
     randoms.push(value[Math.floor(Math.random()*value.length)]);
  }
  return randoms.join('');
}
```

But if you looking for a shorter syntax one in **ES6**:

```
const getRandomStrings = length => Math.random().toString(36).substr(-length);
```

Answer (score 2):

Generate any number of hexadecimal character (e.g. 32):

```
(function(max){let r='';for(let i=0;i<max/13;i++)r+=(Math.random()+1).toString(16).substring(2);return r.substring(0,max).toUpperCase()})(32);
```

Answer (score 2):

Posting an ES6-compatible version for posterity.  If this is called a lot, be sure to store the .length values into constant variables.

```
// USAGE:
//      RandomString(5);
//      RandomString(5, 'all');
//      RandomString(5, 'characters', '0123456789');
const RandomString = (length, style = 'frictionless', characters = '') => {
    const Styles = {
        'all':          allCharacters,
        'frictionless': frictionless,
        'characters':   provided
    }

    let result              = '';
    const allCharacters     = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    const frictionless      = 'ABCDEFGHJKMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz23456789';
    const provided          = characters;

    const generate = (set) => {
        return set.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * set.length));
    };

    for ( let i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
        switch(Styles[style]) {
            case Styles.all:
                result += generate(allCharacters);
                break;
            case Styles.frictionless:
                result += generate(frictionless);
                break;
            case Styles.characters:
                result += generate(provided);
                break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

export default RandomString;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
",,,,,".replace(/,/g,function (){return "AzByC0xDwEv9FuGt8HsIrJ7qKpLo6MnNmO5lPkQj4RiShT3gUfVe2WdXcY1bZa".charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()*62))});
```

Comment: too much regex. Too slow.

Answer (score 1):

This stores 5 alphanumeric characters in variable c.

```
for(var c = ''; c.length < 5;) c += Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I loved the brievety of doubletap's Math.random().toString(36).substring(7) answer, but not that it had so many collisions as hacklikecrack correctly pointed out.  It generated 11-chacter strings but has a duplicate rate of 11% in a sample size of 1 million.

Here's a longer (but still short) and slower alternative that had only 133 duplicates in a sample space of 1 million.  In rare cases the string will still be shorter than 11 chars:

```
Math.abs(Math.random().toString().split('')
    .reduce(function(p,c){return (p<<5)-p+c})).toString(36).substr(0,11);
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is for firefox chrome code (addons and the like)**

```
function randomBytes( amount )
{
    let bytes = Cc[ '@mozilla.org/security/random-generator;1' ]

        .getService         ( Ci.nsIRandomGenerator )
        .generateRandomBytes( amount, ''            )

    return bytes.reduce( bytes2Number )


    function bytes2Number( previousValue, currentValue, index, array )
    {
      return Math.pow( 256, index ) * currentValue + previousValue
    }
}
```

Use it as:

```
let   strlen   = 5
    , radix    = 36
    , filename = randomBytes( strlen ).toString( radix ).splice( - strlen )
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the characters as the `thisArg` in the map function will create a "one-liner":

```
Array.apply(null, Array(5))
.map(function(){ 
    return this[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.length)];
}, "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
.join('');
```

Answer (score 1):

Random numeric value (up to 16 digits)

```
/**
 * Random numeric value (up to 16 digits)
 * @returns {String}
 */
function randomUid () {
  return String(Math.floor(Math.random() * 9e15))
}

// randomUid() -> "3676724552601324"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different approach with fixed length by base, without RegExp replace lack (based on @bendytree's answer);

```
function rand(base) {
    // default base 10
    base = (base >= 2 && base <= 36) ? base : 10;
    for (var i = 0, ret = []; i < base; i++) {
        ret[i] = ((Math.random() * base) | 0).toString(base)
            // include 0-9a-zA-Z?
            // [Math.random() < .5 ? 'toString' : 'toUpperCase']();
    }
    return ret.join('');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As several people here have pointed out, passing the result of `Math.random()` directly to `.string(36)` has several problems.

It has poor randomness. The number of characters generated varies, and on average depends on the tricky details of how floating-point numbers work in Javascript. It seems to work if I am trying to generate 11 characters or fewer, but not with more than 11. And it is not flexible. There is no easy way to allow or prohibit certain characters.

I have a compact solution, which doesn't have these problems, for anyone using lodash:

```
_.range(11).map(i => _.sample("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789")).join('')
```

If you want to allow certain characters (such as uppercase letters) or prohibit certain characters (like ambiguous characters such as `l` and `1`), modify the string above.

Answer (score 1):

I just write a simple package to generate a random token with given size, seed and mask. FYI.

`@sibevin/random-token` - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sibevin/random-token

```
import { RandomToken } from '@sibevin/random-token'

RandomToken.gen({ length: 32 })
// JxpwdIA37LlHan4otl55PZYyyZrEdsQT

RandomToken.gen({ length: 32, seed: 'alphabet' })
// NbbtqjmHWJGdibjoesgomGHulEJKnwcI

RandomToken.gen({ length: 32, seed: 'number' })
// 33541506785847193366752025692500

RandomToken.gen({ length: 32, seed: 'oct' })
// 76032641643460774414624667410327

RandomToken.gen({ length: 32, seed: 'hex' })
// 07dc6320bf1c03811df7339dbf2c82c3

RandomToken.gen({ length: 32, seed: 'abc' })
// bcabcbbcaaabcccabaabcacbcbbabbac

RandomToken.gen({ length: 32, mask: '123abcABC' })
// vhZp88dKzRZGxfQHqfx7DOL8jKTkWUuO
```

Answer (score 1):

How about extending the String object like so.

```
String.prototype.random = function(length) {
   var result = '';
   for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      result += this.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * this.length));
   }

   return result;
};
```

using it:

```
console.log("ABCDEFG".random(5));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function generate(length) {
  var letters = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"];
  var IDtext = "";
  var i = 0;
  while (i < length) {
    var letterIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length);
    var letter = letters[letterIndex];
    IDtext = IDtext + letter;
    i++;
  }
  console.log(IDtext)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[..."abcdefghijklmnopqrsuvwxyz0123456789"].map((e, i, a) => a[Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length)]).join('')
```

Answer (score 1):

Generate random strings with aA-zZ and 0-9 charachters collection.
Just call this function with length parameter.

So to answer to this question: `generateRandomString(5)`

```
generateRandomString(length){
    let result = "", seeds

    for(let i = 0; i < length - 1; i++){
        //Generate seeds array, that will be the bag from where randomly select generated char
        seeds = [
            Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 48,
            Math.floor(Math.random() * 25) + 65,
            Math.floor(Math.random() * 25) + 97
        ]
        
        //Choise randomly from seeds, convert to char and append to result
        result += String.fromCharCode(seeds[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)])
    }

    return result
}
```

Version that generates strings without numbers:

```
generateRandomString(length){
    let result = "", seeds

    for(let i = 0; i < length - 1; i++){
        seeds = [
            Math.floor(Math.random() * 25) + 65,
            Math.floor(Math.random() * 25) + 97
        ]
        result += String.fromCharCode(seeds[Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)])
    }

    return result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In one line

```
Array.from({ length: 5 }, i => String.fromCharCode(Math.round(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 25) + 65))).join('');
```

Comment: Note that this only returns uppercase letters

Answer (score 0):

Another nice way to randomize a string from the characters `A-Za-z0-9`:

```
function randomString(length) {
    if ( length <= 0 ) return "";
    var getChunk = function(){
        var i, //index iterator
            rand = Math.random()*10e16, //execute random once
            bin = rand.toString(2).substr(2,10), //random binary sequence
            lcase = (rand.toString(36)+"0000000000").substr(0,10), //lower case random string
            ucase = lcase.toUpperCase(), //upper case random string
            a = [lcase,ucase], //position them in an array in index 0 and 1
            str = ""; //the chunk string
        b = rand.toString(2).substr(2,10);
        for ( i=0; i<10; i++ )
            str += a[bin[i]][i]; //gets the next character, depends on the bit in the same position as the character - that way it will decide what case to put next
        return str;
    },
    str = ""; //the result string
    while ( str.length < length  )
        str += getChunk();
    str = str.substr(0,length);
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The npm module [anyid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/anyid) provides flexible API to generate various kinds of string ID / code.

```
const id = anyid().encode('Aa0').length(5).random().id();
```

Answer (score 0):

In below code I am generating random code for 8 characters

```
function RandomUnique(){
                    var charBank = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ012346789";
                    var random= '';
                    var howmanycharacters = 8;
                    for (var i = 0; i < howmanycharacters ; i++) {
                        random+= charBank[parseInt(Math.random() * charBank.lenght)];
                    }
                    return random;
                }
        var random = RandomUnique();
        console.log(random);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, what I use every time:

```js
function myFunction() {
        var hash = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ012346789";
        var random8 = '';
        for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            random8 += hash[parseInt(Math.random()*hash.length)];
        }
        console.log(random8);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Your 5 character string ===> "+random8;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to genarate 5 character random string .</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Teach a man to fish:

Programmers cut paper with lasers, not chainsaws. Using fringe, language specific methods to produce the smallest, most obfuscated code is cute and all, but will never offer a complete solution. You have to use the right tool for the job.

What you want is a string of characters, and characters are represented by bytes. And, we can represent a byte in JavaScript using a number. So then, we should generate a list of these numbers, and cast them as strings. You don't need Date, or base64; Math.random() will get you a number, and String.fromCharCode() will turn it into a string. Easy.

But, which number equals which character? UTF-8 is the primary standard used on the web to interpret bytes as characters (although JavaScript uses UTF-16 internally, they overlap). The programmer's way of solving this problem is to look into the documentation.

UTF-8 lists all the keys on the keyboard in the numbers between 0 and 128. Some are non-printing. Simply pick out the characters you want in your random strings, and search for them, using randomly generated numbers.

Bellow is a function that takes a virtually infinite length, generates a random number in a loop, and searches for all the printing characters in the lower 128 UTF-8 codes. Entropy is inherent, since not all random numbers will hit every time (non-printing characters, white space, etc). It will also perform faster as you add more characters.

I've included most of the optimizations discussed in the thread:

- The double tilde is faster than Math.floor
- "if" statements are faster than regular expressions
- pushing to an array is faster than string concatenation

```js
function randomID(len) {
  var char;
  var arr = [];
  var len = len || 5;

  do {
    char = ~~(Math.random() * 128);

    if ((
        (char > 47 && char < 58) || // 0-9
        (char > 64 && char < 91) || // A-Z
        (char > 96 && char < 123) // a-z

        // || (char > 32 && char < 48) // !"#$%&,()*+'-./
        // || (char > 59 && char < 65) // <=>?@
        // || (char > 90 && char < 97) // [\]^_`
        // || (char > 123 && char < 127) // {|}~
      )
      //security conscious removals: " ' \ ` 
      //&& (char != 34 && char != 39 && char != 92 && char != 96) 

    ) { arr.push(String.fromCharCode(char)) }

  } while (arr.length < len);

  return arr.join('')
}

var input = document.getElementById('length');

input.onfocus = function() { input.value = ''; }

document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
  var view = document.getElementById('string');
  var is_number = str => ! Number.isNaN( parseInt(str));
    
  if ( is_number(input.value))
    view.innerText = randomID(input.value);
  else
    view.innerText = 'Enter a number';
}
```

```css
#length {
  width: 3em;
  color: #484848;
}

#string {
  color: #E83838;
  font-family: 'sans-serif';
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<input id="length" type="text" value='#'/>
<input id="button" type="button" value="Generate" />
<p id="string"></p>
```

Why do it in this tedious way? Because you can. You're a programmer. You can make a computer do anything! Besides, what if you want a string of Hebrew characters? It's not hard. Find those characters in the UTF-8 standard and search for them. Free yourself from these McDonald methods like toString(36).

Sometimes, dropping down to a lower level of abstraction is what's needed to create a real solution. Understanding the fundamental principals at hand can allow you to customize your code how you'd like. Maybe you want an infinitely generated string to fill a circular buffer? Maybe you want all of your generated strings to be palindromes? Why hold yourself back?

Comment: Omg... maintaining this code would be a pain. Too hacky and not readable. Always write code for humans, that can eventually be executed by a machine, not the opposite. And all this unnecessary micro-optimization is pure evil... CPU cycles are cheap. It really doesn't matter if pushing to an array is faster than concatenating or if the cryptic double tilde is faster than `Math.floor`.

Comment: This is all opinion based. This code has been running flawlessly since I wrote it for this answer. I use it in a distributed system that broadcasts updates and generates thousands of unique IDs per minute, during high throughput. The ease of un-commenting a line to add characters is so simple. I don't see much room for programmers in your philosophy of "Don't to it if it doesn't need to be done".

Comment: I dont know. All humans want to program and forget that there is a machine in front of them. in the 80s it was good to know math for programming. Today its a nice to have? Is it really a big deal to read a chained condition? No! Not for me! Well language is important. but speaking functions and symbols are for me a nice to have. combine of both worlds and you are a skilled programmer! I cannot believe the downvote. this is not stack overflow

Comment: You misunderstood me @Duco. I don't preach "Don't to it if it doesn't need to be done". I don't know from where you concluded that, once I never said something like this. Actually, I'm very often criticized of reinventing the wheel and I'm proud of it! Avoiding libraries and doing it ourselves is good... sometimes! There's a limit. `Math.floor` is part of the core, for example. My main complain here is that the code is hacky and hard to read. BTW, commented code to be used later is also bad practice. Make your function take another parameter if you want to control its behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a String prototype which can generate a random String with a given length.

You also can secify if you want special chars and you can avoid some.

```
/**
 * STRING PROTOTYPE RANDOM GENERATOR
 * Used to generate a random string
 * @param {Boolean} specialChars
 * @param {Number} length
 * @param {String} avoidChars
 */
String.prototype.randomGenerator = function (specialChars = false, length = 1, avoidChars = '') {
    let _pattern = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    _pattern += specialChars === true ? '(){}[]+-*/=' : '';
    if (avoidChars && avoidChars.length) {
        for (let char of avoidChars) {
            _pattern = _pattern.replace(char, '');
        }
    }
    let _random = '';
    for (let element of new Array(parseInt(length))) {
        _random += _pattern.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * _pattern.length));
    }
    return _random;
};
```

You can use like this :

```
// Generate password with specialChars which contains 10 chars and avoid iIlL chars
var password = String().randomGenerator(true, 10, 'iIlL');
```

Comment: Generally it is considered bad practice to extend native objects (you might release Cthulhu). See - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice

Answer (score 0):

You could use base64:

```
function randomString(length)
{
    var rtn = "";

    do {
        rtn += btoa("" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000)).substring(0, length);
    }
    while(rtn.length < length);

    return rtn;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

recursive solution:

```
function generateRamdomId (seedStr) {
const len = seedStr.length
console.log('possibleStr', seedStr , ' len ', len)
if(len <= 1){
    return seedStr
}
const randomValidIndex  = Math.floor(Math.random() * len)
const randomChar = seedStr[randomValidIndex]
const chunk1 = seedStr.slice(0, randomValidIndex)
const chunk2 = seedStr.slice(randomValidIndex +1)
const possibleStrWithoutRandomChar = chunk1.concat(chunk2)

return randomChar + generateRamdomId(possibleStrWithoutRandomChar)
```

}

you can use with the seed you want , dont repeat chars if you dont rea.  Example

```
generateRandomId("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789")
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple method:

```
function randomString(length) {
    let chars = [], output = '';
    for (let i = 32; i < 127; i ++) {
        chars.push(String.fromCharCode(i));
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i ++) {
        output += chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length )];
    }
    return output;
}
```

If you want more or less characters change the "127" to something else.

Answer (score 0):

## Review

Many answers base on trick `Math.random().toString(36)` but the problem of this approach is that Math.random not always produce number which has at least 5 characters in base 36 e.g.

```js
let testRnd = n => console.log(`num dec: ${n}, num base36: ${n.toString(36)}, string: ${n.toString(36).substr(2, 5)}`);


[
  Math.random(),
  // and much more less than 0.5...
  0.5,
  0.50077160493827161,
  0.5015432098765432,
  0.5023148148148148,
  0.5030864197530864,
  // and much more....
  0.9799597050754459
].map(n=>testRnd(n));

console.log('... and so on');
```

```html
Each of below example (except first) numbers result with less than 5 characters (which not meet OP question requirements)
```

Here is "generator" which allows manually find such numbers

```js
function base36Todec(hex) {
  hex = hex.split(/\./);
  return (parseInt(hex[1],36))*(36**-hex[1].length)+ +(parseInt(hex[0],36));
}

function calc(hex) {
  let dec = base36Todec(hex);
  msg.innerHTML = `dec: <b>${dec}</b><br>hex test: <b>${dec.toString(36)}</b>`
} 

function calc2(dec) {
  msg2.innerHTML = `dec: <b>${dec}</b><br>hex test: <b>${(+dec).toString(36)}</b>`
} 

let init="0.za1";
inp.value=init;
calc(init);
```

```html
Type number in range 0-1 using base 36 (0-9,a-z) with less than 5 digits after dot<br>
<input oninput="calc(this.value)" id="inp" /><div id="msg"></div>
<br>
If above <i>hex test</i> give more digits than 5 after dot - then you can try to copy dec number to below field and join some digit to dec num right side and/or change last digit - it sometimes also produce hex with less digits<br>
<input oninput="calc2(this.value)" /><br><div id="msg2"></div>
```

I already give answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62504318/860099) so I will not put here another solution

Answer (score 0):

The following code will produce a cryptographically secured random string of size containing `[a-zA-Z0-9]`, using an npm package `crypto-random-string`. Install it using:

```
npm install crypto-random-string
```

To get a random string of 30 characters in the set [a-zA-Z0-9]:

```
const cryptoRandomString = require('crypto-random-string');
cryptoRandomString({length: 100, type: 'base64'}).replace(/[/+=]/g,'').substr(-30);
```

Summary: We are replacing /, +, = in a large random base64 string and getting the last N characters.

**PS:** Use -N in `substr`

Answer (score 0):

In case you cannot type out a charset, using `String.fromCharCode` and a ranged `Math.random` allows you to create random strings in any Unicode codepoint range. For example, if you want `17` random Tibetan characters, you can input `ranstr(17,0xf00,0xfff)`, where `(0xf00,0xfff)` corresponds to the Tibetan Unicode block. In my implementation, the generator will spit out `ASCII` text if you do not specify a codepoint range.

```js
    function ranchar(a,b) {
       a = (a === undefined ? 0 : a);
       b = (b === undefined ? 127 : b);
       return String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * (b - a) + a)); 
    }
    
    function ranstr(len,a,b) {
      a = a || 32;
      var result = '';
      for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
       result += ranchar(a,b)
      }
      return result;
    }


//Here are some examples from random Unicode blocks
console.log('In Latin Basic block: '+ ranstr(10,0x0000,0x007f))
console.log('In Latin-1 Supplement block: '+ ranstr(10,0x0080,0x0ff))
console.log('In Currency Symbols block: ' + ranstr(10,0x20a0,0x20cf))
console.log('In Letterlike Symbols block: ' + ranstr(10,0x2100,0x214f))
console.log('In Dingbats block:' + ranstr(10,0x2700,0x27bf))
```

Answer (score 0):

Love this SO question and their answers. So cleaver and creative solutions were proposed. I came up with mine that is wrapped inside a **function** that receives the **length** of the string you want to obtain plus a **mode** argument to decide how you want it to be composed.

**Mode** is a 3 length string that accepts only '1s' and '0s' that define what subsets of characters you want to include in the final string. It is grouped by 3 different subset( [0-9], [A-B], [a-b])

```
'100': [0-9]
'010': [A-B]
'101': [0-9] + [a-b]
'111': [0-9] + [A-B] + [a-b]
```

There are 8 possible combinations (2^N, witn N:#subsets).
The '000' mode return an empty string.

```
function randomStr(l = 1, mode = '111') {
    if (mode === '000') return '';
    const r = (n) => Math.floor(Math.random() * n);
    const m = [...mode].map((v, i) => parseInt(v, 10) * (i + 1)).filter(Boolean).map((v) => v - 1);
    return [...new Array(l)].reduce((a) => a + String.fromCharCode([(48 + r(10)), (65 + r(26)), (97 + r(26))][m[r(m.length)]]), '')
}
```

A simple use case will be:

```
random = randomStr(50, '101')
// ii3deu9i4jk6dp4gx43g3059vss9uf7w239jl4itv0cth5tj3e
// Will give you a String[50] composed of [0-9] && [a-b] chars only.
```

The main idea here is to use the UNICODE table instead of randomizing hexadecimals as I saw in many answers. THe power of this approach is that you can extend it very easily to include others subsets of the UNICODE table with litte extra code in there that a random int(16) can't do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Web Crypto's API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/getRandomValues):

```js
console.log(self.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(1))[0])
```

(original answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349404/generate-random-string-characters-in-javascript#comment57138482_1349404))

Comment: This only generates random numeric strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
function generateRandomStringLettersAndNumbers(maxLength): string {
  return crypto.randomBytes(maxLength).toString('hex').substring(0, maxLength);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A reduced random alphanumeric with upper and lowercase:

```js
const l = 98 // length

// Node
Array.from(crypto.randomBytes(l)).reduce((s, b) => s + (b % 35).toString(36)[(b % 2) - 1 ? 'toLowerCase' : 'toUpperCase'](), '')

// Browser [WebCrypto] (Thanks to Nabulosar in comments, check his comment if you use it)
Array.from(crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(l))).reduce((s, b) => s + (b % 35).toString(36)[(b % 2) - 1 ? 'toLowerCase' : 'toUpperCase'](), '')
```

Answer (score -1):

I use `var randId = 'rand' + new Date().getTime();`

Comment: That's the opposite of random. If you need randomized IDs and generate multiple IDs in, say, a for-loop using this method, you'll probably get some identical IDs. Further, users can influence your ID choice by setting their computer's date/time. That's not something you likely want to do.

Comment: it really depends for what you need it in my case i needed to add id to line when user adds row and you cant click twice in 1 ms,

Comment: You can, however, double click just as some background process or other piece of JavaScript code hangs the browser for a few milliseconds, which causes the next two click events to be handled within the 'same' millisecond. It's unlikely it will happen, sure, but it's not impossible. Therefore the code is unpredictable. Especially if you cant guarentee running time and such on all devices your website/app will be running on.

Comment: i would like to see a demo of that, in my opinion that's not possible, unless you click with a bot 

Comment: Here you go: https://gist.github.com/JochemKuijpers/86217cec7c860c0af0dfc06bbddacc42 I managed to get a few identical IDs on Chrome (easily reproducible on my 6th gen i5 machine). I can imagine this is even more an issue on mobile browsers with less accurate timers.

Comment: thanks thats if you generate multiple ids after 1 click event, i needed to add to a table "1" row and needed unique id  and there was no way that user can click it so fast, but if you have loop then sure i would never use such a thing

Comment: No, those are multiple click events behind handled sequentially within the same millisecond. They are queued up because some other code is hanging the browser. JavaScript does not have concurrent code execution (at least; not for click events), so the browser has to wait for the stalling bit of code to finish before it can handle the click events. Anyway, well, if it works for you, go ahead. Just know the risks that a slow computer or a computer with an inaccurate timer might generate identical IDs.

Comment: got you, yes you need to know the case,

Answer (score -1):

Above All answers are perfect. but I am adding which is very good and rapid to generate any random string value

```js
function randomStringGenerator(stringLength) {
  var randomString = ""; // Empty value of the selective variable
  const allCharacters = "'`~!@#$%^&*()_+-={}[]:;\'<>?,./|\\ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'"; // listing of all alpha-numeric letters
  while (stringLength--) {
    randomString += allCharacters.substr(Math.floor((Math.random() * allCharacters.length) + 1), 1); // selecting any value from allCharacters varible by using Math.random()
  }
  return randomString; // returns the generated alpha-numeric string
}

console.log(randomStringGenerator(10));//call function by entering the random string you want
```

or

```js
console.log(Date.now())// it will produce random thirteen numeric character value every time.
console.log(Date.now().toString().length)// print length of the generated string
```

Comment: `Date.now()` most certainly does _not_ produce thirteen "random" digits

Comment: @Molomby, brother, I appreciate your time but please write the logic in which case it will not produce thirteen "random" digits.

Comment: Randomness is [the lack of predictability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness). The digits produced by `Date.now()` represent the current date/time of the machine on which the function is called. They are _highly_ predictable and simply not "random" by any stretch of the definition.

True randomness is hard; even `Math.random()` isn't truly random, it's pseudorandom. You'll see other answers in this thread recommending the `crypto` module which is better (but still not truly random).

Start here for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/RNG

Answer (score -1):

//creates a random code which is 10 in lenght,you can change it to yours at your will

```
function createRandomCode(length) {
    let randomCodes = '';
    let characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    let charactersLength = characters.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
        randomCodes += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength))
    }
    console.log("your reference code is: ".toLocaleUpperCase() + randomCodes);
 };
 createRandomCode(10)
```

Comment: This is just one of the top answers with very minor modifications.

Comment: i just tried making it more easier and readable.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a perfect solution, but it should work. If you ever get any error, then increase the value given in Uint8Array() constructor. The advantage of this method is it uses [getRandomValues()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/getRandomValues) method that generates cryptographically strong random values.

```js
var array = new Uint8Array(20);
crypto.getRandomValues(array);
var arrayEncoded =  btoa(String.fromCharCode(...array)).split('');
var arrayFiltered = arrayEncoded.filter(value => {
    switch (value){
    case "+" :
        return false;
    case "/" :
        return false;
    case "=" :
        return false;
    default :
      return true;
   }
});
var password = arrayFiltered.slice(0,5).join('');
console.log(password);
```

**A compact Version**

```js
var array = new Uint8Array(20);
crypto.getRandomValues(array);
var password = btoa(String.fromCharCode(...array)).split('').filter(value => {
        return !['+', '/' ,'='].includes(value);
}).slice(0,5).join('');
console.log(password);
```

Answer (score -1):

To generate a hash from an array as a salt, `[0,1,2,3]` in this example, by this way we may be able to retrieve the hash later to populate a condition.

Simply feed a random array, or use as extra safe and fast finger-printing of arrays.

```js
/* This method is very fast and is suitable into intensive loops */
/* Return a mix of uppercase and lowercase chars */

/* This will always output the same hash, since the salt array is the same */
console.log(
  btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array( [0,1,2,3] )))
)

/* Always output a random hex hash of here: 30 chars  */
console.log(
  btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array( Array(30).fill().map(() => Math.round(Math.random() * 30)) )))
)
```

Use HMAC from crypto API, for more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56416039/2494754

Answer (score -2):

Here is an example in CoffeeScript:

```
String::add_Random_Letters   = (size )->
                                         charSet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
                                         @ + (charSet[Math.floor(Math.random() * charSet.length)]  for i in [1..size]).join('')
```

which can be used

```
value = "abc_"
value_with_exta_5_random_letters = value.add_Random_Letters(5)
```

Answer (score -3):

Here's Coffeescript version one line of code

```
genRandomString = (length,set) -> [0...length].map( -> set.charAt Math.floor(Math.random() * set.length)).join('')
```

Usage:

```
genRandomString 5, 'ABCDEFTGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
```

Output:

```
'FHOOV' # random string of length 5 in possible set A~Z
```

Answer (score -3):

//To return a random letter

```
let alpha = "ABCDEFGHIGKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
console.log(alpha.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)));
```

Comment: Please avoid posting solutions that already exists.