# AJAX calls for database information

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, ms-access

I insert a record into the database by making an async AJAX call. After the browser was closed and I opened Access, it was added properly. The problem is that, after i made a call for update, i later made call for select to read updated values. But it still shows old values. Why doesn't the database get updated till I close the browser?

P.S. This problem comes only for IE. Works fine with chrome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your page is cached.

Set the correct no cache headers on the Ajax Response.

See: 
[Prevent browser caching of jQuery AJAX call result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367786/prevent-caching-of-ajax-call)