# use jQuery .get() to grab a specific element

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to use ajax to grab an element with a specific class from another file using jQuery, parse the html to get some data out of it and put it into an object, then display the data in different markup than the original html within #content, an element on the main page..

When using load(), I can target a specific class:

```
$("#content").load("article.html .cover", function(){
    console.log("load() success");
});
```

This works, but I don't want the html from article.html to be put into #content, so I tried using ajax() so that I can manipulate the html before displaying it in the callback:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "article.html .cover"
}).done(function(){
console.log("ajax() success");
});
```

but this results in a 404 error. get() results are the same as ajax().

```
$.get("article.html .cover", function(){
    console.log("get() success");
});
```

How can I use get() to target this specific element?

Comment: Fetch inside the `done()` callback where you have access to the HTML

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
$.get("article.html", function(html){
   var cover = $(html).find('.cover');
});
```

There's no magic in [$.get](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) as it seems to be in [$.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to find a specific element in the page. You can get any file type with `$.get`, and it would not make sense to add a selector when fetching a json file, for example.

*Edit*

If you care about performance, apparently `$.get` uses cache by default ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10610089/607162)).

You can (should?) also return *only* what is needed, if your server-side code allows it. Maybe requesting `articlecover.html` insted of `article.html`.

Comment: just outa curiosity, why would `$.get("article.html .cover")` return a 404?

Comment: Because it is not a valid url.

Comment: oh, okay, I guess that is looking for a URL and not a query string, lol thank you

Comment: That's it, $.get does not target specifically html files, like $.load.

Comment: This works, but I was hoping to find a way of doing this without requesting the entire page. I'm going to be looping through lots of files that may include lots of images and wanted to keep the amount of excess to a minimum. Will this make a negligible difference to load time?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `$.load` is also requesting the whole page. I mean, jQuery will not filter your html _on the server side_. If you want to reduce traffic, think about returning just the part you need. That said, I _think_ that `$.get` uses caching by default.

Comment: You can check the requests in your browser by hitting F12 and going to the _Network_ tab in firefox or chrome.