# Force reload all page resources, not from cache

Tags: javascript, caching, google-chrome, browser-cache

I would like to do something similiar to opening the developer tools in chrome and checking disable cache and then reload the page.

I can't modify the urls in any way (eg. appending a timestamp in the query) as this will work once, but next time I reload the page normally, the resources will load from the old url without the timestamp and be the old cached version.

I only need support for chrome and I don't have access to the server.

Basically I need the resource files to be update in the chrome cache, without altering the url.

Comment: I doubt it is possible all by client side, because the controll of resource caching is handled by server.

Answer (score 1):

referring from this topic: [Prevent browser caching of jQuery AJAX call result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367786/prevent-caching-of-ajax-call)

As you are able to editing the server-side script to setting no cache header, it is hard to handler it perfectly on IE. The only way can do for client side is unfortunately adding timestamp on end of the query string.

Comment: I don't have access to the server at all, however I only need support for chrome.

Comment: **+1** time stamp. Indeed it's unfortunate the SO Poster can't use this method. Perhaps some type of Chrome plugin does this? Dunno.

Comment: no need plugin to do so: http://christian.roy.name/blog/disable-cache-chrome.
BTW, @Tyilo, it'd better to deal with user for setting no cache chrome or talk to server-side part.

Comment: Excellent *Answer* Cauliturtle!

Answer (score 1):

In **Chrome** reloading all page resources regardless cache can be forced by *long pressing* **Refresh** button while developer tools is open