# SQL query returns a null after first iteration

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

*Please dont mind syntax errors, this is just a gist for the whole code*

I got this webpage with the JS code below:

```
setInterval(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: my_page.php,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
      console.log(data.key);
    }
  });
}, 1000);
```

And my_page.php looks like this:

```
include database.php
$data = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("valid SELECT query"), MYSQL_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($data);
```

(Chrome) console shows this:

```
correct_result
null
null
...
```

Can anybody explain why? I have tested the query and is 100% correct, it echoes the correct result on first iteration anyway.

Thanks!

Comment: try `console.log(data)` to see what is coming through.

Comment: 1:object>key>correct_value 2:object>key>null so on...

Comment: In firebug are you seeing each call and the response?

Comment: That blows my mind, we'll need to see more code or maybe try disabling ajax caching http://stackoverflow.com/a/735101/1130734

Comment: What do you get if you run my_page.php directly?

Comment: Try changing to a POST or add a random parameter - try to knock out any cache that might be playing up. Otherwise, as Petah said - more code to see what else could be going wrong.