# jQuery.get doesn't receive latest version of file on server

Tags: javascript, apache, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prevent caching of AJAX call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367786/prevent-caching-of-ajax-call)

I'm using jQuery to read a tiny text file on a web server:

```
jQuery.get('scores.txt', function(data) {
    parseScores(data);
});
```

This nearly works as it should -- but it doesn't reliably load the latest version of the file. Even if `story.txt` has changed, refreshing the page returns exactly the same value for `data`.

The server is standard Mac OS Apache, with no caching enabled, and it's the same machine as the client -- so in theory there are no other caches sitting between me and it.

If I load `http://127.0.0.1/scores.txt` into the browser then it always opens the latest version.

Looking at the Apache log, for the times the page fails to update, the jQuery GET request never reaches the server.

I have a suspicion that I might need to move this question to serverfault.com, but can anyone see a problem with my JavaScript that would make it behave in this way?

Is there any way of using JavaScript/jQuery to force the browser to request a new copy of the file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Server? Maybe  the client ( Browser ) has a cache level...what kind of browser do you use?

Comment: Mountain Lion Safari, but I found the same thing happened using Internet Explorer on a VM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding [`cache: false`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to your AJAX options:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'scores.txt',
    dataType: 'text',
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    success: parseScores
});
```

jQuery will automatically add a cache-preventing timestamp to each request.

Comment: +1 for my preferred method :)

Comment: This works perfectly. Very much appreciated. Five minutes until I can click 'accept'...

Comment: If you want to keep using `$.get()`, you can also use `$.ajaxSetup({cache: false});` at the top of your script to apply the option to all AJAX calls made after that.

Answer (score 6):

You can add a unique identifier to each request to stop the browser caching the response. Just because the client is on the same device as the web server, that does not stop the browser caching the response (nor will it prevent some proxy servers getting involved in the right environment).

```
jQuery.get('scores.txt', {
    now: jQuery.now()
}, function(data) {
    parseScores(data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I've accepted the answer above because it seems like the most elegant way of achieving the same result -- but I can see that this would work just as well. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

add a cachebuster (e.g. timestamp) to the file name like this.

```
jQuery.get('scores.txt?' + (+new Date()), function(data) {
   parseScores(data);
})
```

Comment: Thanks @Matt. I have yet to have my morning coffee :-)

Comment: Thanks to you as well. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use a cache buster.

JQuery's Ajax method has a cache setting to do this for you: https://learntech.imsu.ox.ac.uk/blog/?p=266

@Peter J's solution is the cleanest if you don't want to cache any server content on a single page: https://stackoverflow.com/a/735101/109941