# Chrome caching pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have a static webpage that is being regenerated by a tool at user request.  When the regeneration is complete, the page reloads. This is not HTTPS. The problem is that the page does not update properly in Chrome.  To be fair, I see the issue sometimes in IE as well, but it seems to be primarily chrome.  I have tried the following with no success:

1. Checking 'Disable cache' in chrome developer tools

2. Appending a random string to the page when reloading, i.e.

```
top.location = top.location.href + "?r=" + jQuery.now();
```

3. Trying various methods of reloading, like history.go(), location.reload(), everything I could find.

 But the problem persists... is there anything else I can try?

Comment: `top.location = top.location.href + "?r=" + jQuery.now();` *will* cause Chrome to reload the page, and ignore whatever caches it has. I'm doubtful that even a rogue Chrome plugin can cause this, but I'd start looking at any proxy/ cache servers between the client and your server.

Comment: is the html being retrieved via ajax?

Comment: @DylanHayes So the page is a report- and an ajax post gets made to regenerate that report via a bunch of bat files and python (not web based).  When that call completes (Im using WebAPI/REST) jQuery asks for a page refresh.

Comment: @Matt it's my IIS8 server hosted on my local machine serving up the pages as I'm deving on this stuff... is there something in IIS I should check for?

Comment: ok so you're not inserting html from an ajax request? By default ajax requests are cached and I've had issues with that in the past so i just wanted to double check. Just for reference this link explains what I was asking about.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367786/prevent-caching-of-ajax-call