# jstree 3.0.2 dynamic tree always loading data from cache instead of making a fresh call to server

Tags: ajax, caching, getjson, jstree

I have a jstree. on load of the page the jstree populates fine from the server as it make a fresh call to server, but after that whenever I refresh the page it will always take the data from cache and not make a call to server , thereby always taking the old data to populate. I am using jstree 3.0.2 version. following is the code which generated the jstree on load of the page .

```
$('#tree').jstree({
'core': {
data:{
'url':'getjstree'   // this is the url which will get the json data from the server
}
}});
```

how do we solve this to get fresh data on each call, one solution which I earlier thought of using is the javascript code to hard refresh by calling

```
location.reload(true);
```

but that did refresh the json data but went into recursive call and thereby hanging the page.
Please help how can we solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using this solved the problem

```
$('#tree').jstree({
'core': {
data:{
'cache':false,
'url':'getjstree'   // this is the url which will get the json data from the server
}
}});
```

Comment: @Sam, take a look at my answer about cleaning localStorage.

Comment: Odd... This solution worked for me while @AndréBonna 's one didn't.

Answer (score 5):

JSTree plugin saves tree state in browser's localStorage with key "jstree". So before calling jstree you should erase that key from localStorage, like this:

```
//Removes jstree cached state from localStorage
localStorage.removeItem('jstree');

$('#tree').jstree({
    'core': {
        data:{
            'url':'getjstree'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This is working with latest version of jstree @good work #Andre

Answer (score 0):

I just added a random parameter at the end of the url... like this

```
'url' : function(node){
    return "/myrequestpath?randParam="+getRandParam();
}
                                                }
```

I defined getRandParam to return a random number between 1 and 1000... It would probably have worked out better and being more robust if I had used a time stamp but this worked for me.  Notice that I used the function version of url but it's the same idea (function works every time but the url may be set only once I don't know that for sure).

Comment: BTW I think is more so a issue with AJAX requests than it is with the the JSTree.  It shows up on the JSTree but the real issue is with AJAX.  Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367786/prevent-browser-caching-of-jquery-ajax-call-result

Answer (score -1):

Clear localstorage still works in 2021

Comment: The only thing this "new" answer does is to repeat what half of the other answers are already saying, including the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25406101/14267427).