# $.post working only once in Chrome(normal) but always in incognoto mode

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
<a id="ad_server_ad" name="1" href="http://google.com">
<img src="xyz.png"></a>
```

Above is my html code:

This is my js code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('a#ad_server_ad').click(function() {
    var name = this.name;

$.post("ajax_test.php",{ test:name },function(data){
                alert(data);
        });


});});
```

And this is my ajax_test.php

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['test']))
{
    echo "Call made successfully" . $_REQUEST['test'];
}
```

The code works perfectly fine for the first ajax call but after that when I open the page again and click on the image once more the ajax call is cancelled as shown in networks/XHR.
If I wait for a few mins it works again but just for once.

Now if I use the same code in Incognito mode it works for all the consecutive click.
I am new to ajax and jquery so help me.

Comment: Do you have an ad blocking extension running on your browser?

Comment: Nopes..no such extensions.

Comment: nopes..that didnt help either..

Comment: But wait, you aren't canceling the default behaviour of anchor click, so sounds like expected result (not sure what it has to do with incognito mode thought...)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, It may involve browser caching. Try to add a random number for each request, i.e. "ajax_test.php?12345".

This should trick the browser to not cache the request. Check this answer: [Prevent browser caching of jQuery AJAX call result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367786/prevent-caching-of-ajax-call)

Comment: `POST` requests aren't cached.

Comment: I too thought that its the issue of cache but the documentation says "Pages fetched with POST are never cached"..
So I am clueless as in what to do..

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT:***   Sounds unrelevant answer, i cannot think how this could be related to described behaviour in question...

You should prevent defaut behaviour of anchor's click:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a#ad_server_ad').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent click anchor default behaviour
        var name = this.name;
        var self = this;
        $.post("ajax_test.php", {
            test: name
        }, function (data) {
            alert(data);
            // to redirect, you could use:
            window.location = self.href;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Well your solution worked and ajax calls are being made now..
But I wanted the default behaviour to work as well..

Comment: And I still dont understand.. why is it working in incognito.

Comment: I know this would work..
The thing is, this defeats my purpose of doing the task of redirecting the user and making ajax calls simultaneously..
I could have had redirected the user from the php file also..

Comment: You cannot make a redirect and ajax call simultaneously. In fact you can BUT you have no garanties the request will have enough time to complete and usually browser cancel it once a redirection is in process