# Ajax cachhing issue in Browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, caching

My JavaScript function is as bellow :

```
function getActivityDiscussed(str,id)
{
            var xmlhttp;    
            if (str=="")
            {
              document.getElementById("list_bottom").innerHTML="";
              return;
            }
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
              xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {// code for IE6, IE5
              xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
              {
                document.getElementById("list_bottom"+id).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
              }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","<?php echo base_url($client_url.'communications/getActivityDiscussed'); ?>/"+str,true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT");
            xmlhttp.send();
 }
```

***This ajax call is not working in IE-9.***

I have cleared the cache by using following code :

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT");
```

But I have to use these code for each ajax request.

Is there any way to disable the cache globally?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my knowledge there is no such mechanism available in JavaScript. You have to repeat it regularly otherwise you can use these code in a function and call the function where you want.

```
function clearBrowserCacheForAjax()
{
   xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
   xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
   xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT");
}
```

In each function you can call the above function.

```
function getActivityDiscussed(str,id)
{
            var xmlhttp;    
            if (str=="")
            {
              document.getElementById("list_bottom").innerHTML="";
              return;
            }
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
              xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {// code for IE6, IE5
              xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
              {
                document.getElementById("list_bottom"+id).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
              }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","<?php echo base_url($client_url.'communications/getActivityDiscussed'); ?>/"+str,true);
            clearBrowserCacheForAjax();
            xmlhttp.send();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add some random number or string for every request which will solve this issue.

check this link.. will be helpful. [Prevent browser caching of jQuery AJAX call result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367786/prevent-caching-of-ajax-call)

Comment: I don't think your solution is best, Because if an user send multiple ajax request then it will fill the browser cache. I have the solution, but I want to set some global config so that there is no repetition of code.

Comment: have you tried using cache: false in jquery for that? <br/><br/> you must have included which methods you have tried and these are not desired.

Comment: Have you gone through my code properly? Before answer read the question thoroughly, If any doubt ask question again I will clarify.

Comment: You can change the call from a GET to a POST. POST by design will not get cached. But if you must use GET then adding a current date time stamp in the query string is the best solution