# How to load two times the same updated csv with d3

Tags: javascript, python, csv, d3.js, flask

Is it possible to load the same csv twice with d3?

I have a flask server which updates a csv file every 10 seconds. I would like to reload the graph of the data every 10 seconds.

I used `setInterval` and inside I reuse

```
d3.csv("static/data.csv", function(error, data) {...
```

But when I print the data variable I always get the same graph, as if the csv didn't change.

When I refresh the page it takes the new data and there is no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a result of browser caching. The easiest workaround is appending a random number, or the datetime stamp to the end of the url.

See this answer: [Prevent browser caching of jQuery AJAX call result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367786/prevent-caching-of-ajax-call)