# Firefox $("#element).load jquery shows old img

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

i have specific problem for firefox. When i change the page, i call load jQuery function

```
$("#all").load("test.php", function() {

    testFunction(); //this function will call Restfull-API, get some 
});
```

This is test.php:

```
<div class="pageContent">

    <div class="testPage">

        <div id="link">
        </div>

        <div id="imageDiv">
            <img id="image"/>
        </div>

        <div id="middleContent">

            <div id="test">
            </div>

            <div id="info">
            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="link_bottom">
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

this is testFunction() which i call when page is loaded

```
function ajaxRequestGetAllianceInfo() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "./ajax_request/test.php",
        data: {}, 
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus + ": " + errorThrown);
        },

        success: function(data){

            drawTestPage(data);

        }

    });
}
```

and on the end we have function for change image src in loaded page:

```
function drawAlliancePage(data){
    $("#imageDiv #image").prop("src",data.image);
}
```

and look what i get: http://prntscr.com/iqs885, this first image not exist in inspect element.
if i click on the right side: http://prntscr.com/iqs8sh or change tab in firefox and when i come back to my tab top image is not exist (this is correct because i need to have only 1 image) on chrome this works correct. I don't know why firefox "cache" this old load html data. Any idea how to fix this? For some page i get this problem for some other page all is works fine.

P.S. This not helps [Prevent browser caching of jQuery AJAX call result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367786/prevent-browser-caching-of-jquery-ajax-call-result)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent browser caching of jQuery AJAX call result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367786/prevent-browser-caching-of-jquery-ajax-call-result)

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367786/prevent-browser-caching-of-jquery-ajax-call-result) this not help

Answer (score -1):

I wind the SOLUTION $(html).focus() :D

P.S. You are all idiot who give me negative rep, and